# Lists in Python

Tags: python, list

Is the List in python homogeneous or heterogeneous?

Comment: Homogeneous. All the elements have to be objects

Comment: @gnibbler It's a deceitful answer. I would downvote if it was possible.

Comment: [12,45,89,103,4879] is an homogenous list. In fact, your question is not well expressed; you should have written: "may a list be heterogenous ?" and have precised under what criterion the homo/hetero-genous aspect is appreciated.

Comment: @eyquem: `It's a deceitful answer. I would downvote if it was possible.` That seems a bit harsh. Why do you think this answer is deceitful? It is 100% correct AFAK. If the elements in a Python list are not objects, what are they in Python speak?

Comment: http://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2011/03/19/dynamic-languages-are-static-languages/

Comment: Warning: Resurrecting this pedantically. In an interview in 2003, the BDFL himself called list elements heterogeneous. There's not a much more authoritative source than that. Reference: http://www.artima.com/intv/speed3.html.

Answer (score 25):

```
>>> def a(): pass
>>> lst=[1,'one',{1:'one'},a,[1,1],(1,),True,set((1,))]
>>> for each in lst:
...    print type(each), str(each)
... 
<type 'int'> 1
<type 'str'> one
<type 'dict'> {1: 'one'}
<type 'function'> <function a at 0x100496938>
<type 'list'> [1, 1]
<type 'tuple'> (1,)
<type 'bool'> True
<type 'set'> set([1])
```

Any questions?

Comment: +1 but for a beginner, this example would be clearer if you declared lst=[1,'1','one',{1:'one'},a] then iterated it in two separate lines.

Comment: @carrot-top. Yes , a question. Considering that all the object have the same structure (a type, a value), you mean that the list is homogenous,as gnibbler and pynator,  don't you ? :)

Comment: @eyquem: Great question. Python *lists* are homogenous actually. The list data type holds ordered muteable lists of Python [objects](http://effbot.org/zone/python-objects.htm). Python objects are heterogeneous, objects can contain arbitrary amounts and kinds of data. All data in Python are objects. Object data can hold scalars like ints, floats, complex data structures like dicts, tuples and other lists. Most items in the language are also objects, and lists can hold an ordered list of these objects.

Comment: @carrot-top _" Python lists are homogenous actually"_ Do you realize that it's exactly the contrary of what your above answer seems to express. A beginner will understand nothing after reading of all this ... list of posts

Comment: @eyquem: `Do you realize that it's exactly the contrary of what your above answer seems to express.` It is not contrary at all. Lists are an ordered, homogeneous, muteable collection of Python objects; objects in Python can be almost anything at all. Since Python objects are various types, a homogeneous list of various types can appear heterogeneous. You just need to truly *grok* what a Python object refers to: almost anything that is actionable...

Comment: http://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2011/03/19/dynamic-languages-are-static-languages/

Comment: I was curious about how Python 2's sorting rules work, so I [looked it up](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.5/Objects/object.c#L739). Basically if the types are not normally sortable, it defaults to these rules: `None` is smaller than everything. Then come numbers, and then compare based on type names. If they're the same name or incomparable numbers (e.g. `complex` and 'int'), fail to sort.

Answer (score 9):

**Lists** in Python can be heterogeneous, but by the general convention it is preferable that they only contain *homogeneous* elements. Python **tuples** are the natural data structure for *heterogeneous* sequences.

Of course you can argue that both tuples and lists are just homogeneous sequences of Python objects, but that is a misleading oversimplification and doesn't add any value.

Since tuples are **immutable** and lists are **mutable** you could also argue that mutability is the real distinction between them. However, that is not how they were intended. More on this can be found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626759/whats-the-difference-between-list-and-tuples-in-python).

Comment: _Lists are meant to be iterated over, tuples are meant to be accessed by position_. A tuple's elements are an ordered sequence, and it's usual for the ordering to convey semantic information. A list's elements, being primarily a predictably iterable collection, will normally at least support the same interface (unless you want to start coding type-checking loops, which are often bad style). With the introduction of `collections.NamedTuple` it became obvious that numerical indexing of tuples was less readable.

Answer (score 8):

The List in Python is heterogeneous - the same list can accept objects of various different types.

There is a snippet [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576718-homogeneous-list/) which gives you a homogeneous list in Python. No idea how that piece of code would perform however.

Answer (score 5):

Please try a simple

```
a=[1, "a"]
```

and see if it throws an error before asking a question.

Btw, it does not.

Comment: In some languages, similar code would "work" - but cast the integer to a string.

Comment: Yes, but you'd see the difference in the list between "1" and 1

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you talk about the direct elements of a list or its indirect elements.

I believe that a list is in reality a list of references, not of objects, and that when the interpeter has to use a list, it knows that in fact it must manipulate the objects to which the references are pointing, not the references themselves: that's the "execution model" of Python, I think.

- What I call **indirect element** of a
  list are the **objects** that
  constitute the **value of the list**.
- What I call **direct elements** are the **references** to these objects  that constitutes the **implementation** of the list.

So:

- considered as a **list of
  references**, a list is
  **homogenous**: all the elements are variables, in the plain sense of
  variable = chunk of memory whose
  value can change (while the value of
  an object never changes)
- considered as a **list of the objects**
  pointed by the references, a list is
  **heterogenous**. The innuendo being that their TYPES are heterogenous.

That's my understanding. I don't know if I am fully right.

Comment: Be careful with the "list of references" or pointer based mental model of objects in Python. See [this discussion](http://effbot.org/zone/call-by-object.htm) on why Python neither passes by reference or value; it passes by object. The same holds for lists. They are an ordered, muteable, iterable collection of objects. Objects are different than "references" which implies pointers.

Comment: @carrot-top Thank you to be interested by this subject. First, I don't understand why you evoke the passing or arguments to functions while I was here above describing how I understand the data model and the execution model of Python. Secondly, I had already read your cited page of effbot, and its link to another page by Fredrik Lundh. I confess that I understand only a little bit of what they speaks about. I am not at my ease with the meaning they give to the word 'object'. It seems that they melt diverse meaning and as a result I understand nothing and find their explanations unclear

Comment: `I am not at my ease with the meaning they give to the word 'object'.` Without a clear understanding of "object" as used by Python, you will be very confused by many of the concepts of the language. It is core concept. `I don't understand why you evoke the passing or arguments to functions...` The discussion regarding *objects* is germane to the understanding of lists as a collection of objects.

Answer (score 1):

One more argument for homogeneity of lists: the [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) and the new `typing` module. The items of `tuple` can be individually typed with `Tuple`:

> `Tuple`, used by listing the element types, for example `Tuple[int, int, str]`. The empty tuple can be typed as `Tuple[()]`. Arbitrary-length homogeneous tuples can be expressed using one type and ellipsis, for example `Tuple[int, ...]`. (The ... here are part of the syntax, a literal ellipsis.)
>   [[reference]](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#the-typing-module)

```
>>> import typing
>>> typing.Tuple[str, int, float]
typing.Tuple[str, int, float]
```

However a `list`, via `typing.List` only accepts a single type parameter:

> `List`, used as `List[element_type]`

```
>>> typing.List[str, int, float]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
TypeError: Too many parameters for typing.List<~T>; actual 3, expected 1
```