# generate list field in json format data

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I need to generate the data in the form of  ndjson/json lines having unique values of columns  in pyspark .
I have 4 columns of different type. I need to take distinct value of columns `indicator`, `name`, `fruits` grouped by column `id` and generate a new column `identifier`.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, BooleanType, StringType, ArrayType

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Example").getOrCreate()

# Define the schema for the DataFrame
schema = StructType([
    StructField("id", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("indicator", BooleanType(), True),
    StructField("name", StringType(), True),
    StructField("fruits", ArrayType(StringType()), True)
])

# Sample data
data = [
    (1, True, "Alice", ["apple", "banana"]),
    (2, False, "Bob", ["orange", "grape"]),
    (1, True, "Charlie", ["banana", "kiwi"])
]

# Create the DataFrame
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=schema)

# Show the DataFrame
df.show()

df.createOrReplaceTempView("table_data")

select id, collect_list(indicator) as indicator,collect_list(name) as name ,collect_list(fruits) as fruits
from table_data
group by id;
```

I get below results:

```
id  indicator   name                  fruits
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   [true]      ["Alice","Charlie"]   [["apple","banana"],["banana","kiwi"]]
2   [false]     ["Bob"]               [["orange","grape"]]
```

**I need results as below in json format:**

```
{ id : 1, identifier : [true, "Alice","Charlie","apple","banana","kiwi"] }
{ id : 2, identifier : [false, "Bob","orange","grape"] }
```

also tried below approach. This generates unique values per column, but I'm not be able find a way to concatenate all other columns into `identifier` column as `list of string` and generate json result.

```
aggregated_df = df.groupBy("id").agg(
    F.collect_set("indicator").alias("indicator"),
    F.collect_set("name").alias("name"),
    F.array_distinct(F.flatten(F.collect_set("fruits"))).alias("fruits")
)

aggregated_df.show(truncate=False)
+---+---------+----------------+---------------------+
|id |indicator|name            |fruits               |
+---+---------+----------------+---------------------+
|1  |[true]   |[Alice, Charlie]|[apple, banana, kiwi]|
|2  |[false]  |[Bob]           |[orange, grape]      |
+---+---------+----------------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your aggregation almost took you where you wanted. You just needed to concatenate everything into 1 single array. You can do this using the [`concat`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.concat.html) function.

So let's use this in your aggregation:

```py
aggregated_df = df.groupBy("id").agg(
    F.concat(
        F.collect_set(F.col("indicator").astype("string")),
        F.collect_set("name"),
        F.array_distinct(F.flatten(F.collect_set("fruits"))),
    ).alias("identifier"),
)
>>> aggregated_df.show(truncate=False)
+---+-------------------------------------------+
|id |identifier                                 |
+---+-------------------------------------------+
|1  |[true, Alice, Charlie, apple, banana, kiwi]|
|2  |[false, Bob, orange, grape]                |
+---+-------------------------------------------+
```

Now, there are 2 ways you can get what you want.

#### Method nr 1

Writing this dataframe to a json file:

```py
aggregated_df.write.mode("overwrite").json("output.json")
```

The output file will look like this:

```json
{"id":1,"identifier":["true","Alice","Charlie","apple","banana","kiwi"]}
{"id":2,"identifier":["false","Bob","orange","grape"]}
```

#### Method nr 2

If you want to do this in memory without writing to disk, you can use a combination of the [`to_json`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.to_json.html?highlight=to_json) and the [`struct`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.struct.html) function to get what you want:

```py
output = aggregated_df.withColumn(
    "my_json_col", F.to_json(F.struct("id", "identifier"))
)
>>> output.show(truncate=False)
+---+-------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id |identifier                                 |my_json_col                                                             |
+---+-------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1  |[true, Alice, Charlie, apple, banana, kiwi]|{"id":1,"identifier":["true","Alice","Charlie","apple","banana","kiwi"]}|
|2  |[false, Bob, orange, grape]                |{"id":2,"identifier":["false","Bob","orange","grape"]}                  |
+---+-------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: awesome. Incase if we need to retain the `boolean` field `indicator` value as is without converting to string like `{"id":1,"identifier":[true,"Alice","Charlie","apple","banana","kiwi"]}`, `concat` fails with message Cannot resolve "concat(collect_set(indicator), collect_set(name), array_distinct(flatten(collect_set(fruits))))" due to data type mismatch: Input to `concat` should all be the same type, but it's ("ARRAY<BOOLEAN>" or "ARRAY<STRING>" or "ARRAY<STRING>").;  As this is change of original question posted, will post new one and share here.

Comment: If you need to retain the boolean type without converting it to a string, you'll need to keep it in a different column, so that your json would have 3 keys: `id`, `identifier`, `array_col`. An array always contains elements of the same type.

Comment: sorry to deviate, I really would like to understand this. As per this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150958/lists-in-python , answer suggests list/array can be heterogeneous (ie. of different data types). Could you please help me clarify?

Comment: Good question! Lists in python might be able to contain different data types. But a pyspark column of a certain type is actually under the hood a Scala object. So while you might be interfacing with Spark using Python, actually Scala code is being executed. You can see the source code for the `ArrayType` [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.5.0/sql/api/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/types/ArrayType.scala). There you can see that each `ArrayType` has an `elementType` field, which specifies what the type is of the elements in your array.