# About text files to arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays, text

I have a large text file that reads like

```
Kyle 40
Greg 91
Reggie 58
```

How would I convert this to an array that looks like this

```
array = ([Kyle, 40], [Greg, 91], [Reggie, 58])
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As @Cosmologicon mentions below, you probably want your array to be a list of tuples, not a tuple of lists. Read up on the difference here: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626759/whats-the-difference-between-list-and-tuples-in-python

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming proper input:

```
array = []
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:       
   for line in f:
      name, value = line.split()
      value = int(value)
      array.append((name, value))
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me... I'm using Python 2.7 if that makes a difference.

Comment: It's not clear from the OP, but you may want to convert the second item to an int. Also the OP's "array" is a tuple of lists, whereas yours is a list of tuples. List of tuples is probably the better way to do it.

Comment: Python claims I have invalid syntax on line 3, "with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:  "       . It specifically points to the word "open".

Comment: @Cosmo, I assumed he meant list of tuples, OP, please clarify otherwise. Also @Keith, `open` should work unless you have it redefined somewhere else.

Comment: Open just isn't working at all... I tried putting it in a different program and it again claimed I had a syntax error.

Comment: @Keith, can you verify your syntax? Also post the line you're trying, if possible.

Comment: @Steve, Hm, haven't used this method before. Good to know. +1 to you.

Comment: Just closed out of the program and opened it again... now it works. Thanks so much for your patience and answer.

Comment: @Keith: My current code does this for you. As you can see, you're appending `(name, value)` to array which is your tuple.

Comment: @Keith: To do that is left as an exercise to the reader. j/k, use `[name, value]` in the append call instead of `(name, value)`.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to Manny's solution:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:       
   myarray = [line.split() for line in f]
```

- `for line in f is` more idiomatic than `for line in f.read()`

Output is in the form:

```
myarray = [['Kyle', '40'], ['Greg', '91'], ['Reggie', '58']]
```

Comment: `strip()` is not needed as `split()` will ignore excess whitespace.  For example, `'  red\n\r\t blue \n'.split()` gives `['red', 'blue']`.

Comment: @Keith Michael: If you really need a tuple of lists then change the second line to `myarray = tuple([line.split() for line in f])`

Answer (score 1):

... or even shorter than presented in the accepted answer:

```
array = [(name, int(i)) for name,i in open(file)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the file, read in each line, strip the newline character off the end, split it in the space character, then convert the second value into an int:

```
array = [(name, int(number)) for name, number in
         (line.strip().split() for line in open('textfile'))]
```