# difference between the parameters in python

Tags: python-2.7

What is the defference between **foo = (1,2,3) and foo = [1,2,3] in python** 
Can any body explain me the difference between them more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

The first is a tuple which is an immutable type.

```
>>> foo = (1,2,3)
>>> foo[0] = 42
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

The second is a list, which is mutable.

```
>>> foo = [1,2,3]
>>> foo[0] = 42
>>> foo
[42, 2, 3]
```

There are other very important differences between lists and tuples. Please see this question and its answers:

- [What's the difference between lists and tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626759/whats-the-difference-between-list-and-tuples-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

foo = (1,2,3) gives you a tuple; foo = [1,2,3] gives you a list. maybe start [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html)?

Comment: Thank you for the info.. I will start with that...