# What is the difference between list and tuples in Python?

Tags: python

What is the difference between list and tuples in css?

tuple and list python program

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between list and tuple (minus immutability) in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9969649/difference-between-list-and-tuple-minus-immutability-in-python)

Comment: `css` as in Cascading Style Sheets? Did you mean `python`?

Answer (score 1):

**List** and **Tuple** in Python are the classes of Python Data Structures. The **list is dynamic**, whereas the **tuple has static characteristics**. This means that lists can be modified whereas tuples cannot be modified, the tuple is faster than the list because of static in nature. Lists are denoted by the square brackets but tuples are denoted as parenthesis.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-difference-between-list-and-tuple/