# Transform "list of tuples" into a flat list or a matrix

Tags: python, list, tuples

With Sqlite, a `select .. from` command returns the results `output`, which prints:

```
>>print output
[(12.2817, 12.2817), (0, 0), (8.52, 8.52)]
```

It seems to be a list of tuples. I would like to either convert `output` to a simple list:

```
[12.2817, 12.2817, 0, 0, 8.52, 8.52]
```

or a 2x3 matrix:

```
12.2817 12.2817
0          0 
8.52     8.52
```

to be read via `output[i][j]`

The flatten command does not do the job for the 1st option, and I have no idea for the second one...

A fast solution would be appreciated, as the real data is much bigger.

Comment: `[(12.2817, 12.2817), (0, 0), (8.52, 8.52)]` is already a 3x2 matrix !? or did i miss something ?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python)

Comment: for the flatten function check itertools module recipes there is already a flatten function example: http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes

Comment: [`[item for sublist in output for item in sublist]`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/952952/1243951) works perfectly and has the advantage that your inner tuples could also be lists; more generally any combination of inner and outer iterable works

Answer (score 159):

By far the fastest (and shortest) solution posted:

```
list(sum(output, ()))
```

About 50% faster than the `itertools` solution, and about 70% faster than the `map` solution.

Comment: @Joel nice, but I wonder how it works? `list(output[0]+output[1]+output[2])` gives the desired result but `list(sum(output))` not. Why? What "magic" does the () do?

Comment: Ok, I should have read the manual *g*. It seems `sum(sequence[, start])`: sum adds `start` which defaults to `0` rather then just starting from `sequence[0]` if it exists and then adding the rest of the elements. Sorry for bothering you.

Comment: This is a  well-known anti-pattern: don't use `sum` to concatenate sequences, it results in a quadratic time algorithm. Indeed, the `sum` function will complain if you try to do this with strings!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: agreed. There are very few use cases where this would be preferable.

Comment: Yes, fast but completely obtuse. You'd have to leave a comment as to what it is actually doing :(

Comment: See my answer for a comparison of this to other techniques which are faster and more Pythonic IMO.

Answer (score 76):

List comprehension approach that works with Iterable types and is faster than other methods shown here.

```
flattened = [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
```

`l` is the list to flatten (called `output` in the OP's case)

---

### timeit tests:

```
l = list(zip(range(99), range(99)))  # list of tuples to flatten
```

#### List comprehension

```
[item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
```

timeit result = 7.67 µs ± 129 ns per loop

#### List extend() method

```
flattened = []
list(flattened.extend(item) for item in l)
```

timeit result = 11 µs ± 433 ns per loop

#### sum()

```
list(sum(l, ()))
```

timeit result = 24.2 µs ± 269 ns per loop

Comment: I had to use this on a large dataset, the list comprehension method was by far the fastest!

Comment: I did a little change to the .extend solution and now performs a bit better. check it out on your timeit to compare

Comment: this is very confusing and I don't understand the syntax here at all. General syntax for list comprehension is `expression for item in list` like `x*2 for x in listONumbers`. So for flattening you would expect an expression like `num for num in sublist for sublist in list` not `num for sublist in list for num in sublist`. how is in the comprehension broken down here?

Answer (score 31):

In Python 2.7, and all versions of Python3, you can use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to flatten a list of iterables. Either with the `*` syntax or the class method.

```
>>> t = [ (1,2), (3,4), (5,6) ]
>>> t
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.chain(*t))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(t))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 16):

**Update**: Flattening using extend but without comprehension and without using list as iterator (fastest)

After checking the next answer to this that provided a faster solution via a list comprehension with `dual for` I did a little tweak and now it performs better, first the execution of list(...) was dragging a big percentage of time, then changing a list comprehension for a simple loop shaved a bit more as well.

The new solution is:

```
l = []
for row in output: l.extend(row)
```

The old one replacing `list` with `[]` (a bit slower but not much):

```
[l.extend(row) for row in output]
```

---

Older (slower):

Flattening with list comprehension

```
l = []
list(l.extend(row) for row in output)
```

---

some timeits for new extend and the improvement gotten by just removing list(...) for [...]:

```
import timeit
t = timeit.timeit
o = "output=list(zip(range(1000000000), range(10000000))); l=[]"
steps_ext = "for row in output: l.extend(row)"
steps_ext_old = "list(l.extend(row) for row in output)"
steps_ext_remove_list = "[l.extend(row) for row in output]"
steps_com = "[item for sublist in output for item in sublist]"

print(f"{steps_ext}\n>>>{t(steps_ext, setup=o, number=10)}")
print(f"{steps_ext_remove_list}\n>>>{t(steps_ext_remove_list, setup=o, number=10)}")
print(f"{steps_com}\n>>>{t(steps_com, setup=o, number=10)}")
print(f"{steps_ext_old}\n>>>{t(steps_ext_old, setup=o, number=10)}")
```

Time it results:

```
for row in output: l.extend(row)                  
>>> 7.022608777000187

[l.extend(row) for row in output]
>>> 9.155910597999991

[item for sublist in output for item in sublist]
>>> 9.920002304000036

list(l.extend(row) for row in output)
>>> 10.703829122000116
```

Answer (score 9):

```
>>> flat_list = []
>>> nested_list = [(1, 2, 4), (0, 9)]
>>> for a_tuple in nested_list:
...     flat_list.extend(list(a_tuple))
... 
>>> flat_list
[1, 2, 4, 0, 9]
>>>
```

you could easily move from list of tuple to single list as shown above.

Answer (score 9):

use `itertools` chain:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([(12.2817, 12.2817), (0, 0), (8.52, 8.52)]))
[12.2817, 12.2817, 0, 0, 8.52, 8.52]
```

Answer (score 7):

Or you can flatten the list like this:

```
reduce(lambda x,y:x+y, map(list, output))
```

Comment: `reduce(lambda x,y:x+y, output)` seems to work directly converting to a long tuple (which can be converted to a list). Why use `map(list, output)` inside the `reduce()` call? Maybe It's more in line with the fact that [tuples are immutable, lists are mutable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/626871/2641825).

Answer (score 5):

This is what `numpy` was made for, both from a data structures, as well as speed perspective.

```
import numpy as np

output = [(12.2817, 12.2817), (0, 0), (8.52, 8.52)]
output_ary = np.array(output)   # this is your matrix 
output_vec = output_ary.ravel() # this is your 1d-array
```

Answer (score 3):

In case of arbitrary nested lists(just in case):

```
def flatten(lst):
    result = []
    for element in lst: 
        if hasattr(element, '__iter__'):
            result.extend(flatten(element))
        else:
            result.append(element)
    return result

>>> flatten(output)
[12.2817, 12.2817, 0, 0, 8.52, 8.52]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def flatten_tuple_list(tuples):
    return list(sum(tuples, ()))


tuples = [(5, 6), (6, 7, 8, 9), (3,)]
print(flatten_tuple_list(tuples))
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts. That’s especially useful here, where your answer is competing for attention with nine other answers. What distinguishes yours? When might this be preferred over well-established answers above?

Comment: Ok sure I will do that

Answer (score 1):

The question mentions that the list of tuples (`output`) is returned by Sqlite `select .. from` command.

Instead of flattening the returned `output`, you could [adjust how sqlite connection returns rows using `row_factory`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3-howto-row-factory) to return a matrix (list of lists/nested lists) with numeric values instead of a list with tuples:

```py
import sqlite3 as db

conn = db.connect('...')
conn.row_factory = lambda cursor, row: list(row) # This will convert the tuple to list.
c = conn.cursor()
output = c.execute('SELECT ... FROM ...').fetchall()
print(output)
# Should print [[12.2817, 12.2817], [0, 0], [8.52, 8.52]]
```