# python: Matching between indexes in a matrix and list

Tags: python, list, tuples

Suppose you have tuple of tuples(looks like a matrix).
Now I want to change its contents, so I convert it into a list.
Suppose that I have the number of rows and cols of the matrix.

How can I match between the indexes in the matrix to the indexes in the list?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Are you saying that you flattened the matrix i.e. you made it a one-dimensional list? Otherwise, the indexes are the same. (Also, please add a minor example of tuple of tuples.)

Comment: exactly. I converted it into one-dimentional.

Answer (score 4):

With a list, you can simply use the `[]` operator again. So, for example:

```
>>> a = [[1,2], [3, 4]]
>>> a[0][0]
1
>>> a[0][1]
2
>>> a[1][0]
3
>>> a[1][1]
4
>>> type(a)
<type 'list'>
>>> type(a[0])
<type 'list'>
>>> type(a[0][0])
<type 'int'>
```

The explanation is simple, the first time, you use the `[]` operator, you get a `list`, so you can use the `[]` operator again. Like this, you can emulate a matrix.

If you want to find the indexes, then you can use this nifty little function:

```
def finder(value_to_find, matrix):
    for r, row in enumerate(matrix):
        for c, col in enumerate(row):
            if col == value_to_find:
                return r, c
```

And, for a demo:

```
>>> a = [[1,2], [3, 4]]
>>> a[0][0]
1
>>> a[0][1]
2
>>> a[1][0]
3
>>> a[1][1]
4
>>> def finder(value_to_find, matrix):
    for r, row in enumerate(matrix):
        for c, col in enumerate(row):
            if col == value_to_find:
                return r, c
>>> finder(4, a)
(1, 1)
```

And here is an explanation with comments:

```
def finder(value_to_find, matrix):
    """
    Function to find the indexes of a given value, on first notice
    @param value_to_find: The value we need to find
    @param matrix: The matrix we are to work with
    @return: A tuple of row, column
    """
    # Looping over the rows (lists within the main matrix)
    for r, row in enumerate(matrix):   # Using enumerate returns the index, r and the value row (which is a list)
        for c, col in enumerate(row):  # Looping over the values in each row, with index c and value col
            if col == value_to_find:  # If the col is equal to the value we want, then we return the row, column tuple
                return r, c
```

If you have a 1-D matrix, then you can look at this solution from Hyperborius:

```
listindex = row * length_of_row + column
```

Comment: hahaha, well, sorry I beat you to it. You need more rep, than I do :)

Comment: I guess this is a nice answer.

Comment: @Games */me thriving for rep*, so busy couldn't turn up on chat BTW has time to answer :P

Comment: and in the opposite way? Thats what im trying to find.

Comment: What do you mean by opposite way?

Comment: I want to match the indexes of the matrix to indexes in the list.

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: @adamco Your list indices will be `listindex = row * width + column` being `width` the length of the row-tuples in your original matrix. (Supposing it is not ragged.)

Comment: Ah, I didn't see comment by Hyperboreus before.

Comment: @Hyperboreus Thanks for noticing the comments that the OP made, the question was badly phrased :(

Answer (score 3):

```
a = [[1,2], [3, 4]]
```

if `a` is the matrix, we can access the individual elements by using two parameters, row and column. Here, `row` refers to the number of list and `column` will refer to the position of the element in the list.

So, `column` is nothing but the normal way of referencing an element in the list and `row` is nothing but the normal way of referencing a list inside a list. Both `row` and `column` are zero based indices.

The format is

```
a[row][column]
```

when we say

```
a[row]
```

it means that, from the list of lists, get the list at position `row` and when we say

```
a[row][column]
```

we say that, from the list which we want, pick the element at position `column`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a tuple of tuples:

```
>>> a = ((1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9))
```

which you converted to a flat list, presumably using a technique like this (credits to Joel Cornett, https://stackoverflow.com/a/10636583/219229):

```
>>> b = list(sum(a, ()))
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Such that `b` effectively lost the original multi-dimensional indexing. If you already know the original index from `a`, you can calculate its index in `b` as following:

```
>>> matrix_width = len(a[0])
... (assuming you have the indices i,j) ...
>>> index_in_b = j*matrix_width + i 
>>> item_to_find = b[index_in_b]
```

If you expand this to multi-dimensional arrays, like 3d-array, and you have indices `i`, `j`, `k`, then it should be `index = i + (j * width) + (k * width * span)`, where `width = a[0][0]`, and `span = a[0]`

---

P/S: Just in case you want to convert it to list of lists, here are some shorthands you can use:

```
>>> b = list[map(list,a)]  # using map
>>> b = [list(x) for x in a]  # using list comprehension
```