# How can i escape this string for sql query?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, escaping

trying to use this query with escaped variables:

```
"UPDATE table_name SET status = ?, status_by = ? WHERE (unique_id, page_id) IN (?)", [req.body.action, req.body.status_by, aSet]
```

but end up getting this error:
'Operand should contain 2 column(s)'

this is how aSet looks: `(1234567890, 123),(1234567890, 123)`

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a `?` placeholder for an entire list, it can only be replaced with a single value.

You need to spread the all the elements of `aSet` into separate parameters, and put enough `?` placeholders in the query for all of them.

```
qs = ",".join(["(?, ?)"]*len(aSet))
sql = """UPDATE table_name SET status = ?, status_by = ? 
    WHERE (unique_id, page_id) IN (%s)"""%(qs)
cur.execute(sql, [req.body.action, req.body.status_by] + list(sum(aSet, ()))
```

I got that `list(sum(aSet, ())` expression from [Transform "list of tuples" into a flat list or a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632839/transform-list-of-tuples-into-a-flat-list-or-a-matrix)