# Saving tuple with numbers to file as string

Tags: python

I'm starting with Python in Machine Learning, I'm interested in solving old Kaggle competition for my own. 
First thing I need to do is to convert list of encoded pixels to a bounding box, convert it to have top left and bottom right rectangle coordinates, have it in specific output and save it to a file

I found already examples where using RLE algorithm convert encoded pixels and I need to change it to save to the file. My particular problem is saving a tuple to a file in `x1,y1,x2,y2` format

I have a code, which takes the first and the last coordinate from the list of pixels. First I tried with:

```py
f = open("file.txt", "w")
f.write(str(mask_pixels[0]) + str(mask_pixels[len(mask_pixels)-1]))
f.write("\n")
f.close()
```

But the output is like `(469, 344)(498, 447)` (which is a tuple, so that's fine).

I tried to use `join` function as following:

```py
coordinates = mask_pixels[0], mask_pixels[len(mask_pixels)-1]
f = open("file.txt", "w")
for x in coordinates:
    f.write(",".join(str(x)))
f.write("\n")
f.close()
```

But it saves it as `(,4,6,9,,, ,3,4,4,)(,4,9,8,,, ,4,4,7,)`

So I tried with

```py
f = open("file.txt", "a")
f.write(str(coordinate1))
f.write(",")
f.write(str(coordinate2))
f.write("\n")
f.close()
```

But it saves it as `(469, 344),(498, 447)`, which is still something I'm not looking for.
Can anyone show me a hint how should I do it to have in a file something like `469,344,498,447`? I'm not asking for a code directly (I know you guys might not have time for it), but I'm looking for an idea what should I read/learn.

Comment: Append all tuples in a list. Then flatten the list from list of tuples. Then write the flattened list to the file.

Comment: Also, you can try this `mask_pixels[0] + mask_pixels[len(mask_pixels)-1]`. Instead of making them into string format, this would join into a single list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transform "list of tuples" into a flat list or a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632839/transform-list-of-tuples-into-a-flat-list-or-a-matrix)

Comment: @Arkistarvh Kltzuonstev with second approach I still have brackets `(469, 344, 498, 447)`, but the first approach looks good, thanks :)

Comment: @SmartManoj might be, thanks for the link, I'll read about it, but it's probably a duplicate after a first glance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open("file.txt", "w") as f:
    print(*sum((mask_pixels[0],mask_pixels[-1]),()),sep=', ',file=f)
```

Output

```
469, 344, 498, 447
```

Comment: Looks ok, but it'll write whole list - as I wrote in my question I need only to save `mask_pixels[0]` and `mask_pixels[len(mask_pixels)-1]`, but thanks for a hit, I'll check it out and use it for my code :)

Answer (score 1):

You can transform your tuples in list and concatenate them :

```
a = (469, 344)
b= (498,447)
result = list(a) + list(b)
```

Output :

```
[469, 344, 498, 447]
```

To go back to your code it could look something like that :

```
f = open("file.txt", "w")
f.write(str(list(str(mask_pixels[0])) + list(str(mask_pixels[len(mask_pixels)-1]))))
f.write("\n")
f.close()
```

---

And if you want to save all of your mask you could even do a double list comprehension :

```
a = (469, 344)
b= (498,447)
c = (512,495)
list_of_tuples = [a, b, c]
result = [item for sublist in list_of_tuples for item in sublist]

Out : [469, 344, 498, 447, 512, 495]
```

Comment: but doesn't `write` expect a str, not a list?

Comment: You're right I forgot to recast as string, thanks !