# Removing parentheses around 2 elements in a list

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list:

```
lst = [('1','one'),('2','two'),('3','three')]
```

I would like to remove the parentheses so that it becomes:

```
lst = ['1','one','2','two','3','three']
```

I tried:

```
lst = [j[0] for j in lst]
```

output:

```
lst = ['1','2','3']
```

can't figure out how to get the other elements in the list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a flat list out of list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transform "list of tuples" into a flat list or a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632839/transform-list-of-tuples-into-a-flat-list-or-a-matrix)