# How to use RegEx for these cases?

Tags: python, regex

Given a string, I need to identify the field after a `$` that may or may not be surrounded by `{ }`:

```
$verb = verb
${verb}age = verb
```

`$$` acts as an escape and I need to account for that as well as it may precede the delimiting `$`.

What I have so far is:

```
reg = r'\$([_a-zA-Z0-9]*)'
s = '$who likes $what'
re.findall(reg, s)
['who', 'what']
```

But I cannot devise the expression for the optional bracing, I tried:

```
reg = r'\$({?[_a-zA-Z0-9]*}?)'
```

But that picks up values such as:

```
${who
$who}
```

What would be the appropriate expression to be able to account for the optional bracing?

**Update:**

When it comes to preceding `$`, the following would be invalid strings:

```
$$verb = invalid
$${verb} = invalid
```

But these would be valid:

```
$$$verb = $verb
$$${verb} = $verb
```

This is because a `$$` is replaced with a single `$` afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the opening `{` should match up with the closing `}` you could use 2 capturing groups with an alternation and then the value will be either in group 1 or group 2.

If the `$` should not be preceded by another `$` you could use a negative lookbehind `(?<!\$)\$` asserting not a dollar sign directly at the left.

```
\$(?:{([_a-zA-Z0-9]+)}|([_a-zA-Z0-9]+))\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7RpcDu/1)

Or to get the values only, you could use an alternation with lookarounds

```
(?<=\$)[_a-zA-Z0-9]+\b|(?<=\${)[_a-zA-Z0-9]+(?=})
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NEF4lA/1)

```
import re

regex = r"(?<=\$)[_a-zA-Z0-9]+\b|(?<=\${)[_a-zA-Z0-9]+(?=})"
test_str = ("$verb = verb\n"
            "${verb}age = verb")

print(re.findall(regex, test_str))
```

Output

```
['verb', 'verb']
```

**EDIT**

For the updated question, for example using capturing groups, you can match either a single or 3 or more dollar signs asserting that what precedes is not a dollar sign.

```
(?<!\$)(?:\$(?:\${2,})?)(?:{([_a-zA-Z0-9]+)}|([_a-zA-Z0-9]+))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Egn9QN/1)

Comment: So the first one is ideal, however for the case where there are preceding `$`, please see my update.

Comment: I posted this comment and then updated the post, did not anticipate you being immediately responsive! Thanks!

Comment: @pasta_sauce Like this? `(?<!\$)(?:\$(?:\$\$)?)(?:{([_a-zA-Z0-9]+)}|([_a-zA-Z0-9]+))` https://regex101.com/r/lUZjvS/1

Comment: @pasta_sauce I have added an update to the answer using a capturing groups example.

Comment: Yes. Because of my lacking RegEx knowledge, is this "flattenable"? It currently returns (in Python) `[(Group1, Group2), (Group1, Group2), ...]`. I assume this is a result from the "capture groups"? Does the other implementation you proposed (alternation with lookaround) solve this?

Comment: @pasta_sauce that is correct. There are ways to flatten the tuples and remove the empty entries. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632839/transform-list-of-tuples-into-a-flat-list-or-a-matrix

Comment: @pasta_sauce There is a longer pattern with lookarounds but it is not that efficient https://regex101.com/r/FtIrok/1

Answer (score -1):

You can get the second set of matches with something like:

> ```
> reg2 = '\$(?:{)([_a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?:})'
> ```

Which makes the bracing mandatory but not captured...