# How to rewrite Pandas frame.append with concat

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, deprecated

I have the following code which works perfectly putting in subtotals and grand totals.  With the frame.append method deprecated how should this be rewritten?

```
pvt = pd.concat([y.append(y.sum()
                           .rename((x, 'Total')))
                for x, y in table.groupby(level=0)
                 ]).append(table.sum()
                                 .rename(('Grand', 'Total')))
```

Prior to this, I created a pivot table.  So I'm looking for the totals to be stacked, not added as another column

```
pivot = pd.pivot_table(data=df2,
            index=['date_created','BuyerName'],
            aggfunc='sum').round()
```

I get the following error with suggestion #2
---> 17     pvt = pd.concat([x for _, y in table.groupby(level=0) for x in (y, y.sum().rename((x, 'Total')))] + 
18                 [table.sum().rename(('Grand', 'Total'))])
'Total')))
25     return(pvt)

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```py
pvt = pd.concat([y for x, y in table.groupby(level=0)] + \
                [y.sum().rename((x, 'Total')) for x, y in table.groupby(level=0)] + \
                [table.sum().rename(('Grand', 'Total'))])

# or

pvt = pd.concat([x for _, y in table.groupby(level=0) for x in (y, y.sum().rename((x, 'Total')))] + \
                [table.sum().rename(('Grand', 'Total'))])
```

Answer (score 0):

Ynjxsjmh's answer wouldn't compile for me, so here's what I ended up using:

```py
pd.concat([x for a, y in table.groupby(level=0) for x in (y, y.sum().rename((a, 'Total')).to_frame().T)] + \
          [table.sum().rename(('Grand', 'Total')).to_frame().T])
```

From what I can tell, the code works like this:

table.groupby(level=0) returns a tuple of (entry_name,subframe) that we can operate on. We want both the original subframe (`y`) and a calculation off the subframe (`y.sum()...`) so we do a [multi-for list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51291027/8954291) to return both of them.

Unfortunately if `y.sum()` returns a series (as it's apt to do) we need to pull it back to a frame with `to_frame()`. I'm not sure why this needs transposed but it fixed some errors I had so ymmv.