# How to create a pointer to a list, such that accessing via the pointer gives immutable elements?

Tags: python, list, tuples, immutability

Assume

```
my_list = [[1], [2], [3], ["a"], [5]]
```

I want

```
my_imm = ImmutableList(mylist)
```

such that

```
my_imm[2][0] = 0
```

would either throw an error, or not change `my_list[2]`.

Is there such a construct *without copying all the data*?

Also assume `my_list` is long, and I wouldn't want a conversion, but rather an lazy iterator.

---

Notice this is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11142397/does-python-have-an-immutable-list), because I want THE ELEMENTS to be immutable.

Tuples won't solve that out of the box.

Comment: do you have access to numpy? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541324/immutable-numpy-array

Comment: @AndrewPye yes, but my elements aren't necessarily numbers

Comment: numpy accepts strings tho... does require that if you have list of lists, that all have same dimensions. otherwise the nested list will be mutable

Comment: @AndrewPye Doesn't numpy copy everything on construction? I have the data input as a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a generator to get the elemets as tuples:

```
my_imm = (tuple(e) for e in my_list)
```

Comment: smaller is better (and you got there before I did) +1

Comment: but doesn't this still create a copy?

Comment: Kind off. It creates tuples with references to the values.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections.abc import Iterable
from typing import Iterator


class MyImm(Iterable):
    def __init__(self, iterable: Iterable):
        self._iterator = iter(iterable)

    def __next__(self) -> Iterator:
        return tuple(next(self._iterator))

    def __iter__(self):
        return self


my_list = [[1], [2], [3], ["a"], [5]]
my_imm = MyImm(my_list)

for i, e in enumerate(my_imm):
    print(my_list)
    if i == 2:
        e[0] = 0

print(my_list)
```

output:

> ```
> "C:/code/EPMD/Kodex/Applications/EPMD-Software/LocationService/ablation/ssss.py",
> line 22, in <module>
>    e[0] = 0 TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment [[1], [2], [3], ['a'], [5]] [[1], [2], [3], ['a'], [5]]
> [[1], [2], [3], ['a'], [5]]
> ```