# Does it matter if you use tuple vs list in installed_apps in Django

Tags: python, django, tuples, pythonanywhere

The Django tutorial says the following, using a list in the installed_apps. But the default is a tuple, and other sources also say that Django prefers tuples rather than lists in this situation.

My question is: If I follow what the tutorial says, and use a list rather than a tuple, will this cause problems elsewhere in the setup? Or does it not really matter?

I am using virtualenv on PythonAnywhere running Django 1.8 and Python 3.4

---

What the tutorial says to add to mysite/settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [ 
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Comment: Can you point to these "other sources"?

Comment: Django has long been inconsistent, but in 1.9 switched all the default settings to use a list rather than a tuple.

Comment: This StackOverflow answer for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12349784/why-does-django-use-tuples-for-settings-and-not-lists. But I see that it is 3 years old so I am guessing from your answer that it's outdated.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, there is a difference. Tuples are *immutable*.

Sometimes it's handy to be able to append something to initial applications list (for example, in 'local' configs, imported at the end of `settings.py`). If you have your `INSTALLED_APPS` in tuple you can only replace the whole value. If you have them in list — you can just append something.

Answer (score 4):

No. Tuples and lists are exactly equivalent here.