# Why did Django 1.9 replace tuples () with lists [] in settings and URLs?

Tags: python, django, list, tuples, django-1.9

**I am bit curious to know why Django 1.9 replaced tuples () with lists [] in settings, URLs and other configuration files**

I just upgraded to Django 1.9 and noticed these changes. What is the logic behind them?

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles'
    ]

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Is anything different because of these changes?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

It is explained in issue [#8846](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8846) (emphasis mine):

> In the documentation for ​Creating your own settings there's a
>   recommendation which reads "For settings that are sequences, use
>   tuples instead of lists. This is purely for performance."
>
> This is bunk. Profiling shows that tuples run no faster than lists for
>   most operations (certainly looping, which we are likely to do most
>   often). On the other hand, **list-literal syntax has the advantage that
>   it doesn't collapse to a single value when you have a single item and
>   omit the trailing comma, like tuple syntax. Using list syntax is no
>   slower, more legible and less error prone.** An often-expressed view in
>   the wider Python community seems that tuples should not be considered
>   as immutable lists. They are intended as fixed-length records - indeed
>   the mathematical concept of a tuple is quite distinct from that of a
>   sequence.

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12363023/2011147) for a more up-to-date discussion.

Another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68712/2011147) (not directly related to this issue) demonstrates that *accessing elements* is actually faster with a `list`.

**Update and further information:** It is correct that the above issue was closed years ago, but I included it because it explained the rationale behind the decision and many similar discussions refer to the same ticket. The actual implementation decision was triggered after the [following discussion on django-developers](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/django-developers/h4FSYWzMJhs/_2iVc4qgfsoJ) started by core Django developer [Aymeric Augustin](https://www.djangoproject.com/~aaugustin/):

> I prefer them *[lists]* for two reasons:
>
> 1) All these settings are sequences of similar things. Such values are
>   best represented with lists, unless they have to be immutable, in
>   which case a tuple can be used. (tuples are both “namedtuples without
>   names” and “immutable lists” in Python.)
>
> 2) Lists aren’t prone to the “missing comma in single-item tuple”
>   problem which bites beginners and experienced pythonistas alike.
>   Django even has code to defend against this mistake for a handful of
>   settings. Search for “tuple_settings” in the source.

And the switch to lists actually happened in [issue #24149](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24149) which also referred to the above discussion.

Answer (score 10):

In [the release notes of 1.9](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.9/#default-settings-that-were-tuples-are-now-lists), there is:

> **Default settings that were tuples are now lists**
>
> The default settings in **django.conf.global_settings** were a combination of lists and tuples. All settings that were formerly tuples are now lists.

So it appears that it was just done for consistency. Both tuples and lists should work fine. If you use a tuple with 1 element, remember the comma `(1,)` because otherwise it's not a tuple but simply an expression in parens.

As for urlpatterns, those used to be defined using a `patterns()` function, but that was deprecated in Django 1.8, as a list of url instances works fine. As the function will be removed in the future, it shouldn't be used in new apps and projects.