# Python add a string to all set's elements

Tags: python, string, set, set-operations

I'm wondering what is the Python way to perform the following - 
Given a set :

```
s = {'s1','s2','s3'}
```

I would like to perform something like :

```
s.addToAll('!')
```

to get

```
{'s1!','s2!','s3!'}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Tuples are immutable. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626759/whats-the-difference-between-list-and-tuples-in-python

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For an actual set:

```
>>> s = {'s1','s2','s3'}
>>> {x + '!' for x in s}
set(['s1!', 's2!', 's3!'])
```

That method is 2.7+, If you are using Python 2.6 you would have to do this instead:

```
>>> s = set(['s1','s2','s3'])
>>> set(x + '!' for x in s)
set(['s1!', 's2!', 's3!'])
```

Comment: nice but I feel he need for tuple your previous answer `[x + '!' for x in s]`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan That would result in a list, need to `tuple()` it still.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I decided to answer the actual question which says sets, it is kind ambiguous so that's why I said "for an actual set"

Comment: Yes jamylak it is ambiguous :) , @StjepanBakrac then `tuple([x + '!' for x in s])` I am also a new Python learner :)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Or just `tuple(x + '!' for x in s)`, submit that if you want, it could be the answer

Comment: @jamylak wait... `>>> (x + '!' for x in s)` doesn't answer tuple but `>>>[x + '!' for x in s]` answer list. theory is not clear to me Why? ..so I used typecast to tuple.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan The `tuple` constructor accepts an iterable to create a new tuple from it. That works with a list, `tuple([x + '!' for x in s])`, as you have shown. In Python if you remove the square brackets in a function call it uses a generator expression instead, which evaluates it's items lazily.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
>>> s = ['s1','s2','s3']
>>> list(i + '!' for i in s)
```

Comment: Check the updated question, this is now wrong. Also you should always use `[i + '!' for i in s]` list comps instead of list constructor