# List and tuple behave differently

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I'm well aware that [there are differences between lists and tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/626759/915501) and that [tuples aren't just constant lists](http://jtauber.com/blog/2006/04/15/python_tuples_are_not_just_constant_lists/), but there are few examples where the two are actually treated differently by the *code* (as opposed to by a coding convention), so I (sloppily) have used them interchangeably.

Then I came across a case where they give totally different behavior:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
>>> a
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
>>> idx = (1,1)
>>> a[idx]
4
>>> idx = [1,1]
>>> a[idx]
array([[3, 4, 5],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```

can someone explain what's going on here? More importantly, where else does this pitfall appear in scipy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting a different behavior because, in numpy, three types of indexing are supported

- Basic Slicing
- Advanced Indexing
- Record Access

Using tuple for indexing is just equivalent to a parameter list, which suffixes as a Basic Slicing, where-as using a non-tuple like list results in Advanced Indexing.

Also remember, from the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing)

> Advanced indexing is triggered when the selection object, obj, is a
>   non-tuple sequence object, an ndarray (of data type integer or bool),
>   or a tuple with at least one sequence object or ndarray (of data type
>   integer or bool). There are two types of advanced indexing: integer
>   and Boolean.
>
> Advanced indexing always returns a copy of the data (contrast with
>   basic slicing that returns a view).

And moreover, from the same documentation

> In Python, x[(exp1, exp2, ..., expN)] is equivalent to x[exp1, exp2,
>   ..., expN]; the latter is just syntactic sugar for the former.