# How to locate position of item in a sublist in python?

Tags: python, list, sublist

I have created a list that looks something like this:

```
items = [["one","two","three"], 1, ["one","two","three"], 2]
```

How do I access e.g. '1' in this list?

Comment: This doesn't truly address the question, but lists shouldn't contain heterogeneous data. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626759/whats-the-difference-between-list-and-tuples-in-python

Instead consider using a tuple for each "set":

`items = [(["one", "two", "three"], 1), (["one", "two", "three"], 2)]`

Then you can get the 1 via items[0][1].

Answer (score 4):

`item[1]` is the correct item. Remember that lists are zero-indexed.

If you wanted to get `one` (The one in the first sublist), then you can do `items[0][0]` Similiarly, for the second sublist, you can do `items[2][0]`

Answer (score 2):

You can access it by index:

```
>>> items = [["one","two","three"], 1, ["one","two","three"], 2]
>>> items[1]
1
```

Or, if you want to find a position of an item in the list by value, use `index()` method:

```
>>> items.index(1)
1
>>> items.index(2)
3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`list.index()`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) to get the index of the value:

```
>>> items = [["one","two","three"], 1, ["one","two","three"], 2]
>>> print items.index(1)
1
```

Then, to access it:

```
>>> print items[1]
1
```

---

However, `list.index()` only returns the first instance. To get multiple indexes, use [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
>>> [i for i, j in enumerate(items) if j == 1]
[1]
```

This loops through the whole list, giving a sort of count along with it. For example, printing `i` and `j`:

```
>>> for i, j in enumerate(items):
...     print i, j
... 
0 ['one', 'two', 'three']
1 1
2 ['one', 'two', 'three']
3 2
```

You can assume that `i` is the index and `j` is the value.