# Bubble Sort help in python - ascending & descending order

Tags: python, algorithm, bubble-sort

So I am new to python and I have a project which requires us to go through a really long tuple list and we have to order the list in descending and ascending order. However, for both my functions I always get ascending order, WHAT IS WRONG? someone please help im really stressed out

```
def bubblesort_descending(tuple_list):
    j = len(tuple_list)
    made_swap = True
    swaps = 0
    while made_swap:
        made_swap = False
        for cnt in range (j-1):
            if tuple_list[cnt] < tuple_list[cnt+1]:
                tuple_list[cnt], tuple_list[cnt+1] = tuple_list[cnt+1], tuple_list[cnt]
                made_swap = True
                swaps = swaps + 1
    return swaps
```

Main Program:

```
elif choice ==  'd':
    unsorted = range(len(numbers))
    shuffle(unsorted)
    print ("Randomised tuple list generated:")
    print
    print (unsorted)

    swaps = bubblesort_descending (unsorted)
    print
    print ("heres the sorted list")
    print
    print (unsorted)
    print
    print (swaps, "swap(s) made")
    print
```

Comment: Why you no use [sorted](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted)?

Comment: @thefourtheye I'm guessing this is a learning exercise.

Comment: It is sorting correctly for me, in descending order. Are you sure you posted both functions?

Comment: Yeap, its working guys I forgot to "return tuple list" lol thanks for the help though !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert that iterator to a list.

```
unsorted = range(10)
unsorted_list = list(unsorted)
```

After this, your code will sort in descending order because you are making a swap if `tuple_list[cnt]` is less than `tuple_list[cnt+1]`. If you change the logical operator from "`<`"to "`>`" you will get ascending order because after changing, you will make swaps if `tuple_list[cnt]` is greater than `tuple_list[cnt+1]`

By naming your list as tuple_list, it is kind of confusing. Because in python lists and tuples are different.
[What's the difference between lists and tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626759/whats-the-difference-between-list-and-tuples-in-python)

Comment: Actually ``range()`` in Python 2 gives you a list. In Python 3 it gives you an iterator of ``<class 'range'>``.

Comment: since he is using prints as functions (print()) i assumed he is not using python 2. So he is not creating a list. For python 3,  I didn't know that. Thanks for info. Updating my answer according to that.

Comment: You cannot make that assumption. ``from __future__ import print_function``.

Comment: "print_function 2.6.0a2 3.0 PEP 3105: Make print a function" from http://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html -- It's been in Python 2.6 for quite some time.

Comment: Ok. Another unknown. Thanks again. =)  Code should work in python 2.6+ because range() would have created list. Since it is not working, it is another thing that makes me assuming he is using python 3. (seems only "right" thing)

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer :) Also update it to place more emphasis on the *logical operator*. This was/is (*I believe*) the OP's basic problem.

Comment: I tried to make it clear why I changed the _logical operator_. I hope it is clear enough. :)

Answer (score 2):

The basic difference between *ascending* and *descending* sorting order is in the **comparison**: Here is a **bubble sort** implementation as taken from http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Bubble_sort#Python:

```
def bubble_sort(lst, asc=True):
    lst = list(lst)  # copy collection to list
    for passesLeft in range(len(lst)-1, 0, -1):
        for i in range(passesLeft):
            if asc:
                if lst[i] > lst[i + 1]:
                    lst[i], lst[i + 1] = lst[i + 1], lst[i]
            else:
                if lst[i] < lst[i + 1]:
                    lst[i], lst[i + 1] = lst[i + 1], lst[i]
    return lst
```

**Note:** The difference based on the `asc` parameter?

*Example:*

```
>>> xs = [1, 2, 9, 4, 0]
>>> bubble_sort(xs, asc=True)
[0, 1, 2, 4, 9]
>>> bubble_sort(xs, asc=False)
[9, 4, 2, 1, 0]
```

So in effect swapping your *logical operator* `<` to `>` reverses the sorting order.