# Hash function on list

Tags: python, hash

I have a list containing 3 fields:

```
[weight, age, marks]
```

I would like to apply hash function on each individual row and store these hash values as list. How to proceed with this?

I have combined the individual lists of weight, age, mark using the `zip()` function:

```
list1=zip(weight,age,marks)
```

Kindly help me with this an I am new to python. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tell us more. What are values of weight, age, marks, how do you expect the hash to look like.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you already have a hash function, like `hash(weight, age, marks)`, and want to store the hash value along with each triplet? Or do you want to use some hash-based collection, like `dict`?

Comment: @javidcf , i applied the hash for a single row of list but  I am unable to apply it on an entire list of hash values using while loop.

Answer (score 5):

You may try to create a hash on tuple structure, like `(1, 444, "fine")` but not on lists like `[1, 444, "fine"]` because it is mutable.

```
In [56]: weight = 120.0

In [57]: age = 99

In [58]: marks = ("a", "b", "cc")

In [59]: row = [weight, age, marks]
```

Trying `hash` on mutable structure like list will fail:

```
In [60]: hash(row)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-60-4a104abdcd18> in <module>()
----> 1 hash(row)

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Tuple is immutable, this will succeed:

```
In [61]: hash(tuple(row))
Out[61]: 1271481222345795008
```

Note, that in my example I have created `marks` as tuple, if you have it as a list, it has to be converted to tuple too:

```
In [62]: marks = ["a", "b", "cc"]

In [63]: hash((weight, age, marks))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-7c8ffc07e716> in <module>()
----> 1 hash((weight, age, marks))

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

In [64]: hash((weight, age, tuple(marks)))
Out[64]: 1271481222345795008
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
map(hash, [weight, age, marks])
```

It gives following list : [ hash(weight), hash(age), hash(marks) ]

Comment: I applied the hash function on list. Now I am storing these hash values in new list, but the while loop is entering infinite loop.    while i in range(len(list1)):
      listhash[i]= hash(list1[i])
      i=i+1
 print "Hash finished"

Comment: @user3577226 Why don't you use the more pythonic : _for i in range(len(list1): listhash[i] = hash(list1[1])_ - Also what is the value of len(list(1)) ?

Comment: I sorry. I just realize that weight, age and marks were lists. I thought they were scalar values.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I understand that you actually have three lists, `weight`, `age` and `marks`, and have built a "table" with all the records with `zip(weight, age, marks)`.

Now, you want to get the hash of each "row". If you want to use Python built-in `hash` function, these rows must be [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object); tuples are immutable, lists are not (if you don't know the difference between tuples and lists, look  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626759/whats-the-difference-between-list-and-tuples-in-python)). That's no problem, because with `zip` each created "row" is actually a tuple. So, to obtain the hash of each row, you may just use the [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) function:

```
hashes = map(hash, list1)
```

Now you have the hash of each row in hashes (note that you could replace `hash` with any custom hash function with a tuple argument, if you want). Now you have all the hashes of your rows in `hashes`, so `hashes[23]` is the hash of the row `list1[23]`, for example. If you want to have everything in a single structure, just `zip` it again:

```
list1_and_hashes = zip(list1, hashes)
```

Note that each element of `list1_and_hashes` is a tuple with two elements: first, the row itself (which is in turn a tuple with its corresponding weight, age and marks), and second, the hash of the row. If you want a table where every element has four fields (weight, age, marks and hash), you could use `map` again with a [lambda function](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk).

```
list1_and_hashes_2 = map(lambda row_hash: list(row_hash[0]) + list(row_hash[1]),
                         list1_and_hashes)
```

Then you will have in `list1_and_hashes_2` the table with four fields in each row.

PD: I'm assuming you are using Python 2. In Python 3, `zip` and `map` do not return lists, but [generators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756096/understanding-generators-in-python); in that case, you may need to wrap some of your calls with `list(...)` to obtain the actual structure.