# How to implement hash on a class holding only a List?

Tags: python

I have the following Python class:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, ints: List[int]) -> None:
        self.ints = ints
    def __eq__(self, other: object) -> bool:
        if not isinstance(other, Test):
            return NotImplemented
        return self.ints == other.ints
```

Because I've overridden the equals method, I should implement the hash method. However, lists are not hashable in Python.

I've read that I can convert the `List` to a `Tuple` and hash that, but this feels a bit hacky. Are there any better options?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hash function on list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23351415/hash-function-on-list)

Comment: If you feel that it's hacky, then how do you expect the hashing to work correctly when you change the inner list? Mutability is the reason `list` is not hashable, `tuple` is immutable and thus is OK to hash

Comment: "Because I've overridden the equals method, I should implement the hash method" why do you say that? That isn't a valid inference. A relevant example: `list` objects implement `__eq__` but they do not implement `__hash__`...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ah interesting. I usually program in Java, where hash and equals methods need to be implemented together. But I suppose Python's restriction on what can be hashed removes that requirement. Thanks!