# Find maximum value of minimum elements in tuple

Tags: python, list, max, minimum

If I have a list

```
[[209, 34], [50, 170], [197, 32], [75, 156], [176, 51], [54, 141], [205, 19], [35, 173]]
```

How would I go about finding the sublist with the maximum minimum element?

ie, in the case above, it would be index`[3]` - `[75,156]` because it's minimum value is greater than the minimum value of all other elements.

Comment: Note: though they are very similar, tuples and lists are distinct types. It's best not to use one term when you mean the other.

Comment: And a great reference for when to use one or the other is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626759/whats-the-difference-between-list-and-tuples-in-python

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be as simple as:

```
max(list_of_iterables, key=min)
```

i.e.:

```
>>> lst = [[209, 34], [50, 170], [197, 32], [75, 156], [176, 51], [54, 141], [205, 19], [35, 173]]
[[209, 34], [50, 170], [197, 32], [75, 156], [176, 51], [54, 141], [205, 19], [35, 173]]
>>> max(lst, key=min)
[75, 156]
```

The `max` (and `min`) functions work by walking through an iterable and comparing each element in the iterable picking out the biggest (or smallest for `min`) element.  The catch is that the thing compared is the result of the `key` function applied to the individual element.  By default, the `key` function is just the identity function -- but it can be anything you want.  In this case, my key function is `min` which picks out the minimum value of the sub-list.  We then compare the sublists based on their minimum value and pick out the `max` which is exactly what your question asked for.

Comment: as the op is probably new to python, some explanation would be helpful, I think

Comment: @bcr -- Yeah, that's probably true.  I've added some explanation.

Comment: will this only compare the first value, or both values in each sub list item?

Comment: @Luke_Smith_Lukasaurus -- It will compare the minumum value of each sublist and then return the sublist whose minimum value is the biggest.  In the case of ties, the first sublist with that minimum value is returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sorted` function.

```
>>> lst = [[209, 34], [50, 170], [197, 32], [75, 156], [176, 51], [54, 141], [205, 19], [35, 173]]
[[209, 34], [50, 170], [197, 32], [75, 156], [176, 51], [54, 141], [205, 19], [35, 173]]
>>> sorted(lst, key=min, reverse=True)
[[75, 156],
 [54, 141],
 [176, 51],
 [50, 170],
 [35, 173],
 [209, 34],
 [197, 32],
 [205, 19]]
```

`key=min` means it will use `min` function when sorting the list.

Then you can find the index of the value with `index` method. Like:

```
>>> lst.index([75, 156])
3
```