# change value 2d array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, replace, tuples

I have an array with 20 values, but value 16 is incorrent and must be replaced with the correct value. How can I do that?

```
texture[16] = 'sky13.jpg'
```

That code does not work for some reason. The error is "'tuple' object does not support item assignment"

Comment: Please recheck what exactly you're using. As the error suggests, you might be using a tuple instead of a list.

Comment: @Defi "The code does not work" deserves error trace sharing with us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're working with a tuple instead of a list.  Convert it to a list first

```
texture = list(texture)
texture[16] = 'sky13.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

check what texture is

```
type(texture)
```

if it is tuple then convert it to list

```
textute = list(texture)
```

in python simple way to talk tuple object is immutable list object

more about differences is here [What's the difference between lists and tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626759/whats-the-difference-between-list-and-tuples)

Answer (score 0):

Tuples in Python are `**inmutable**`, which means that you can't change the value once you assign it!

You need to convert the tuple to a list:

```
listOfTextures = list(texture)
```

And then you will be able to change the values you want to.