# Comparing one list to another with ==

Tags: python, list

I tried the following program in ipython

```
In [1]: a = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7)

In [2]: b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

In [3]: a
Out[3]: (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)

In [4]: b
Out[4]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

In [5]: a == b
Out[5]: False
```

In the above program what is the difference between `a` and `b`? Why is `a==b` returning False?

Comment: a is a tuple and b is a list. check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626759/whats-the-difference-between-list-and-tuples

Answer (score 2):

Your `a` is a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#tuple), uses round brackets `()`, while your `b` is a [list](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list), uses square brackets `[]`, so they are not of the same data type and the comparison fails, although they contain the same items:

```
>>> a = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) # round brackets declare a tuple
>>> b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] # square brackets declare a list
>>> type(a)
<type 'tuple'>
>>> type(b)
<type 'list'>
>>> a == b
False
```

For the comparison you need to get them to be of the same type first, then you can compare the contents:

```
>>> list(a) == b
True
>>> a == tuple(b)
True
>>> c = [1,2,3]
>>> b == c
False
```

Answer (score 2):

a and b have different types.  Instead, try these:

```
a == tuple(b)
list(a) == b
```

Comment: I think it is better to not assume b is list or a is a tuple and do: `list(a) == list(b)` or `tuple(a) == tuple(b)`

Comment: @Elisha: sure.  In that case, tuple on both sides should be slightly faster.

Answer (score 1):

You are not comparing two lists, but a list with a tuple.

```
In [1]: a = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7)

In [2]: b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

In [3]: type(a)
Out[3]: tuple

In [4]: type(b)
Out[4]: list
```

Answer (score 0):

In your program a is not list but tuple. That is why it is failing on the check. To check type you can use [type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type) function. You can use [list](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list) function to typecast tuple to list for check as follows:

```
>>> a = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
>>> b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
>>> 
>>> a == b
False
>>> type(a)
<type 'tuple'>
>>> type(b)
<type 'list'>
>>> 
>>> list(a) == b
True
```