# Return multiple vars: list/tuple

Tags: python, arrays, list, tuples

I have a function which must return many values (statistics) for other function to interact with them. So I thought about returning them inside a list (array). But then I wondered: should I do so using a list (`["foo", "bar"]`) or using a tuple (`("foo", "bar")`)? what are the problems or differences there are when using one instead of the other??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a tuple. In your application, it doesn't seem like you will want or need to change the list of results after.

Though, with many return values you might want to consider returning a dictionary with named values. That way is more flexible and extensible, as adding a new statistic doesn't requiring modifying every single time you use the function.

Comment: Ah yeah, the dict is the best option, thanks you solved my headache hehe.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not need to edit the return value, use a tuple. The main difference is that lists can be edited.

See this: [What's the difference between lists and tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626759/whats-the-difference-between-list-and-tuples)

Comment: No, I don't need to do so. Thanks very much, I didn't know. :=).