# How to store (type and time) in a list in python?

Tags: python

Hi I want to create a list which stores both type and time attribute.Type will be a or b.And time is random between 0 and 100.For example l[0]=(a,5).I know how to create a list but i do not know how to do this.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post the code you have so far.

Comment: Thank you sir.I havent started anything as i am trying to learn python.If you give me an idea on how to proceed,i will be able to come up with something.

Comment: what is the nature of type a,b! Is it the type of the variable ? or the type that you have already created ?

Comment: Type a or b is just an indication.For example if a fruit is apple or orange.a=orange,b=apple.

Comment: If you post the code you have it will give a better indication of your intentions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store lists inside a list, and you can also store a tuple inside a list.

Let's give a quick example here, to explain the above-mentioned comment. Let's suppose that we are going to store the number and the type of number ("Even" or "Odd").

- "E"= Even number: is a number that is multiple of 2.
- "O"= Odd number of not.

Suppose that we have a list of numbers from 1 to 10.

```
l= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

In this case, you have two choices to store the number and the type of this number (Odd/Even). You can store them using List of lists, or list of tuples.

If you wanna use list of tuples

```
listOfTuples= []
for x in l:
    if x%2==0:
        listOfTuples+=[(x,'E')] #Equivalent to listTypes.append((x,'E'))
    else: 
        listOfTuples+=[(x,'O')] #Equivalent to listTypes.append((x,'O'))
print listOfTuples
```

Result:

```
[(1, 'O'), (2, 'E'), (3, 'O'), (4, 'E'), (5, 'O'), (6, 'E'), (7, 'O'), (8, 'E'), (9, 'O'), (10, 'E')]
```

If you wanna use list of lists

```
listOfLists= []
for x in l:
    if x%2==0:
        listOfLists+=[[x,'E']] #Equivalent to listTypes.append((x,'E'))
    else: 
        listOfLists+=[[x,'O']] #Equivalent to listTypes.append((x,'O'))

print listOfLists
```

Result:

```
[[1, 'O'], [2, 'E'], [3, 'O'], [4, 'E'], [5, 'O'], [6, 'E'], [7, 'O'], [8, 'E'], [9, 'O'], [10, 'E']]
```

The choice between tuples and lists shouldn't be taken naively. There is a difference between both, Tuples are fast and memory efficient. But, once you create a tuple, you cannot edit it, it is immutable. Lists on the other hand are mutable, you can edit them.

You can re-edit your list of lists by assigning directly a new value.

```
listOfLists[3][0]="test"
```

The result would be:

```
[[1, 'O'], [2, 'E'], [3, 'O'], ['test', 'E'], [5, 'O'], [6, 'E'], [7, 'O'], [8, 'E'], [9, 'O'], [10, 'E']]
```

But, you can do that if you store your objects using tuples:

```
listOfTuples[3][0]="test"
```

You'll get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 30, in <module>
    listOfTuples[3][0]="test"
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

For more information about the difference between tuples and list in python, check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626759/whats-the-difference-between-list-and-tuples).

Comment: it is the equivalent to extend not append, considering you are using a tuple you should be using append, there is no reason to use a list

Comment: Exactly what i wanted.Thank you so much.