# Sort tuple by averages

Tags: python, sorting, tuples

I have a tuple which currently looks like the following:

```
[['Hussain', 7, 8, 0], ['Max', 3, 4, 3], ['Alexandra', 10, 9, 8]]
```

I want to be able to sort this tuple so that it prints out the tuple in order from highest to lowest averages. This is what I expect as the outcome:

```
['Alexandra', 9],['Hussain', 5],['Max', 3.3333333333]
```

I would appreciate any help given.

TIA

Comment: btw, you have a list not a tuple

Comment: Oh al right, then what differentiates a list and a tuple? - I've totally forgotten.

Comment: Check this post out to learn about the differences: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626759/whats-the-difference-between-list-and-tuples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from statistics import mean
from operator import itemgetter
l = [['Hussain', 7, 8, 0], ['Max', 3, 4, 3], ['Alexandra', 10, 9, 8]]

print(sorted(([ele[0],mean(ele[1:])] for ele in l),key=itemgetter(1),reverse=True))

[['Alexandra', 9.0], ['Hussain', 5.0], ['Max', 3.3333333333333335]]
```

If you are not using python >= 3.4 you can just do the average calculation  manually.

```
print(sorted(([ele[0],sum((ele[1:])) /  len(l) - 1] for ele in l),key=itemgetter(1),reverse=True))
```

`ele[0],mean(ele[1:])` takes the name and the remaining elements which are the scores, we then sort using `itemgetter(1)` which is the score/second element as the key and setting `reverse=True` to go from high to low.

I would also use `itertools.islice` to get the slice avoiding building new lists with normal slicing:

```
from itertools import islice
print(sorted(([ele[0],mean(islice(ele,1,None))] for ele in l),key=itemgetter(1),reverse=True))
```

Or without using mean:

```
from itertools import islice
print(sorted(([ele[0],sum(islice(ele,1,None)) / len(l) - 1] for ele in l),key=itemgetter(1),reverse=True))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I really do appreciate it :)

Comment: Is "ele" a python syntax? or is it something you have used as like an index.

Comment: @Hussain, it is just a variable name, you could call it anything you want

Comment: Thanks just wanted to clarify

Comment: I understand the use of `itertools.islice` but which parts are you splitting here?

Comment: @Hussain, instead of creating slices which normal slicing does  islice returns an islice  object that is basically an iterator  so more memory efficient. Not an issue in your code but on larger datasets it may well be.

Answer (score 1):

```
s = [['Hussain', 7, 8, 0], ['Max', 3, 4, 3], ['Alexandra', 10, 9, 8]]
result = sorted([[e[0], sum(e[1:])/len(e[1:])] for e in s], key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

Comment: Sorted needs an iterable. 

I'm using list comprehension to give sorted the first parameter: [[e[0], sum(e[1:])/len(e[1:])] for e in s]  = > [['Hussain', 5.0], ['Max', 3.3333333333333335], ['Alexandra', 9.0]]

Comment: I used timeit to see how our functions compare. With number=10000, your answer gets: 1.5141523819997929
Mine gets: 0.08450542999980826

Comment: Your first answer:
from statistics import mean
from operator import itemgetter
sorted(([ele[0],mean(ele[1:])] for ele in l),key=itemgetter(1),reverse=True)

Maybe the imports slow it down. Anyway, what's the problem with my answer? It's fast, one line, clear and list comprehensions are great.

Comment: Dude, why did you delete your comments?