# Which is faster to return from method in Python - list or tuple?

Tags: python, list, tuples

Got this question during Python Dev interview.

> If you have to chose what to return from function tuple or list, what
>   considerations would you have? (Other than the fact list is mutable
>   and tuple is not.)

Different performance?
Something else?

Comment: what on earth makes you think that? they are *both* py_objects on the heap. the good news is that the method only has to return a pointer so there isnt any copying either way.

Comment: If performance is the same, what's different then?

Comment: This is something you can discover yourself through profiling.

Comment: @AlexB lists are mutable and tuples aren't?

Comment: What's the difference [between a list and a tuple?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626759/whats-the-difference-between-list-and-tuples)

Comment: @zamuz difference between returning list from method vs tuple. why would you go for one or another?

Comment: @AlexB - Performance will be roughly equal on most python implementations (benchmark both if you are concerned).  Use a list if it needs to be mutated and it's a collection of objects with no fixed size (you append to the list as its being built).  If you need to store a group of names/test scores, etc (where you may add or remove some scores) use a list. Use a tuple if its not going to be mutated and the fixed order in the tuple defines it's meaning. E.g., tuples are perfect for returning coordinates (latitude, longitude) or a group of attributes about an employee `(name, salary, id_str)`.

Comment: @dr jimbob. Interviewer said it's not the mutability. But thank you, it is still very informative.