# Why do lists have a __reverse__() special method but tuples don't in Python?

Tags: python, list, tuples, python-internals, c-api

The [`reversed(seq)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) built-in in Python indicates that `seq` must have a `__reversed__()` method or support the sequence protocol. Lists and tuples both obviously support the sequence protocol, but lists have their own `__reversed__()` method used instead.

```
>>> hasattr(list, '__reversed__')
True
>>> hasattr(tuple, '__reversed__')
False
```

Then there must be some faster optimization in `__reverse__()` for a list than the sequence protocol would provide for reversing. So I took a look at the [source code where `__reversed__()` is implemented](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c6880edaf6f3/Objects/listobject.c#l2986) for listobject.c, and with my pitifully limited C knowledge I cannot understand why a tuple ([tupleobject.c](https://bitbucket.org/python_mirrors/cpython/src/d81d4b3059e4e5dca67515315c2ada6dfe1c52a4/Objects/tupleobject.c?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default)) wouldn't have similar internal reversing methods, as a tuple appears to me to bean array with some optimizations (`PyTuple_MAXSAVESIZE`) on allocations and memory, and a list to be a more familiar array.

What is the C magic I am missing that makes implementing a `__reversed__()` method an optimization for the list type, but the standard iterator protocol better for tuples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tuples simply rarely are iterated over in reverse order.

That's because tuples are *heterogenous*, lists are *homogenous*; while lists have order, tuples are meant to have *structure*. As result, tuples are meant to be relatively *small*, while lists can be (very) large. See [What's the difference between lists and tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626759/whats-the-difference-between-list-and-tuples/626871#626871)

As such, there is simply no need to create a reverse iterator for tuples; it would be a premature optimisation, creating a maintenance cost for very little gain.

Comment: Ah, so I was seeing it as an optimization to _not_ have a `__reversed__()` method for tuples, but it's really just a matter of not being worth implementing, didn't even consider that for some reason, immediately thought optimization. Thanks!