# If len Statement

Tags: python, if-statement, variable-length-array

I type in seven digits to be able to work out a gtin-8 product code. But if I type in more than seven digits, the if len statement is meant to recognise that I have typed in more than seven digits, but it doesn't. I tried putting this into an variable but that did not work either... Any help would be appreciated!!! This is my code........

```
gtin1 = int(input("Enter your first digit... "))
gtin2 = int(input("Enter your second digit... "))
gtin3 = int(input("Enter your third digit... "))
gtin4 = int(input("Enter your fourth digit... "))
gtin5 = int(input("Enter your fifth digit... "))
gtin6 = int(input("Enter your sixth digit... "))
gtin7 = int(input("Enter your seventh digit... "))

gtin_join = (gtin1, gtin2, gtin3, gtin4, gtin5, gtin6, gtin7) 

if len(gtin_join) == 7:
```

Comment: Why do you have your program setup to enter one digit at a time? Why don't you just type in the entire code

Comment: of course it does not since each input() call, no matter what you type in (even 8,3,2,1) for example is interpreted as 1 thing. This this is of type string.

Comment: If you're going to enter one number at a time, you should also check each is a single digit. Alternatively, get the user to enter a single number and just check it's `< 10000000`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably want to do is something like that (notice that I'm using a list here):

```
ls = []
while len(ls) < 7:
    try: #always check the input
        num = int(input("Enter your {0} digit:".format(len(ls)+1) ))
        ls.append(num)
    except: 
        print("Input couldn't be converted!")

print(ls) #ls now has 7 elements
```

Your created tuple always has a length of 7 so your `if`-statement always turns out to be `True`.

For the difference between list and tuple please see this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626759/whats-the-difference-between-list-and-tuples).

Answer (score -1):

Your gtin_join is tuple, and if you want list you should use square braces. You can test type of variables with this example:

```
gtin1 = int(input("Enter your first digit... "))
gtin2 = int(input("Enter your second digit... "))
gtin3 = int(input("Enter your third digit... "))
gtin4 = int(input("Enter your fourth digit... "))
gtin5 = int(input("Enter your fifth digit... "))
gtin6 = int(input("Enter your sixth digit... "))
gtin7 = int(input("Enter your seventh digit... "))

gtin_join = (gtin1, gtin2, gtin3, gtin4, gtin5, gtin6, gtin7)

print(type(gtin_join))

gtin_join = [gtin1, gtin2, gtin3, gtin4, gtin5, gtin6, gtin7]

print(type(gtin_join))

if len(gtin_join) == 7:
    print 7
```

Answer (score -1):

I would do the following:

```
gtin_list = []
while len(gtin_list) != 7:
    gtin = input("Please enter all 7 digits separated by commas...")
    gtin_list = [int(x) for x in gtin.split(",")]
```