# What do these lines of code do?

Tags: python, numpy

I am working with `numpy`. I encountered this line of code.

```
a = (1.,80.,5.)
```

What does this mean? At some other line, I found

```
aList = np.arange(a[0], a[1]+a[2], a[2])
```

**Note:** `np` is namespace assigned from `numpy`.

Comment: Have a read of https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html this will help to understand the basics of lists, dictionaries, tuples, and sets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a` is a *tuple* of floats. A tuple is a kind of structure that is kinda like a *list*, but is *immutable* (i.e. you cannot modify any of its components once it has been created). But, like a list it can be indexed.

In theory, some tuples have special names, for example a tuple of 2 is called a pair, a tuple of 3 is called a triplet etc (people don't necessarily call them that, but it helps a bit more to understand what a tuple is about).
Because it's immutable, conceptually it is thought of more as a unique object, rather than as a collection of ones; for this reason it can also be validly used as a key to a dictionary (as opposed to lists which cannot).

To create a tuple, you create a comma-separated sequence of objects inside parentheses, i.e. `()` (as opposed to brackets, i.e. `[]` that you would to create a list).

As for floats, the float `3.0` can also be written `3.` for short.

The `numpy.arange` function then creates a range by calling it using the components of the tuple as arguments. In your particular case, it will create a range of numbers from 1 to 80+5, at increments of 5.

A very cool use of tuples is that they can be expanded into a sequence of arguments to a function. e.g. if you had a tuple `a = (1.,10.,2.)`, and you wanted to call `numpy.arange(a[0], a[1], a[2])`, you could just do `numpy.arange(*a)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

For the first code segment you are creating a tuple with 3 numbers 1, 80 and 5 in this.

```
a=(1.,80.,5.)
1.0, 80.0, 5.0)
```

In the second code segment you are arranging a list with evenly spaced values from 1 to 81 (because you are adding a[1](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) and a[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626759/whats-the-difference-between-list-and-tuples)) with intevals of 5.

```
np.arange(a[0], a[1]+a[2], a[2]) 
array([  1.,   6.,  11.,  16.,  21.,  26.,  31.,  36.,  41.,  46.,  51.,
        56.,  61.,  66.,  71.,  76.,  81.])
```

From the [numpy help](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html)

> **numpy.arange** ([start, ]stop, [step, ]dtype=None)
>
> Return evenly spaced values within a given interval.
>
> Values are generated within the half-open interval [start, stop) (in other words, the interval including start but excluding stop). For integer arguments the function is equivalent to the Python built-in range function, but returns an ndarray rather than a list.

**EDIT** As a.smiet pointed out the code creates a tuple and not a list. There are differences between the two as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626759/whats-the-difference-between-list-and-tuples)

Comment: Actually the first segment creates a tuple, not a list. And the second line creates evenly spaced values from 1 to 81 and not 80...

Answer (score 0):

First line is just a tuple.

Second line is using the `np.arange` method which returns venly spaced values within a given interval:

`np.arange(start, stop, step)`

The parameters you have are using the tuple, `a`.
Where `a[0] = 1` and `a[1] = 80` so on...

Answer (score 0):

```
a = (1.,80.,5.)
```

Creates a tuple of 3 floats (1.0, 80.0 and 5.0).

```
aList = np.arange(a[0], a[1]+a[2], a[2])
```

Created this list:

```
[  1.   6.  11.  16.  21.  26.  31.  36.  41.  46.  51.  56.  61.  66.  71. 76.  81.]
```

Which, according to http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html means thats 1.0 is a start, 85.0 (which is 80+5) is an end and 5.0 is a step (parameters of the function) for creating spaced values.

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, it is a tuple of 3 items:

```
>>> a = (1.,80.,5.)
>>> a
(1.0, 80.0, 5.0)
```

For the second one, it generates a list (start: 1.0, end: 80.0 + 5.0, step: 5.0):

```
>>> a_list = numpy.arange(a[0], a[1]+a[2], a[2])
>>> a_list
array([  1.,   6.,  11.,  16.,  21.,  26.,  31.,  36.,  41.,  46.,  51.,
        56.,  61.,  66.,  71.,  76.,  81.])
```