# What is the data model required for such data?

Tags: c

Using python syntax, we have deep list like,

Example 1 - `list =   [1, [2, 3], 4]`

Example 2 - `list =   [[1, [1, 1]], 1, [1, 1]]`

where each subset **MUST** be of class `list` or `int` at runtime.

Using C language, What is the data model required to maintain such data?

Note: Dimensions are not fixed, as per the example

Comment: Are you looking for a datamodel or a datastructure? You choose the data structure list clearly.

Comment: @randominstanceOfLivingThing I use term data model for term data structure

Comment: An array of pointers to arrays of ints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a forward declaration of a structure for the elements.

```
// declare existence of a structure type to be used for array elements.
struct some_type_S;

// The list type is a count and pointer to an array of `struct some_type_S`
// Alternative: use a variable length array for `element`
typedef struct list_S {
  size_t num_elements;
  struct some_type_S *element;
  // Alternative: use C99 and a variable length array for `element`
  // struct some_type_S element[];
} list_T;

// Now define `struct some_type_S` as
// a flag (is_int) and a union of an `int` and a pointer to a list
typedef struct some_type_S {
  _Bool is_int;
  union {
    int i;
    list_T *list;
  } u;
} some_type_T;
```

Happy C coding.

Comment: Do u name `list_S` as deep list? or just list? what is the terminology?

Comment: @overexchange "deep list" or "list" --> your choice.  To me a list is a list is a list.  "deep list" is not a regularly used term in C, yet to seems to apply in other languages.

Comment: list is an enumeration of homogenous elements. `[1, [1,2], 3]` is not a list, right? Because `[1,2]` is not homogenous to `1` and `3`

Comment: @equivalency "list is an enumeration of homogeneous elements."  --> Where is that specificied?  C does not define _list_ that way nor [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/list).  IAC, in this data, `struct some_type_S`, aka `some_type_T`, is the _homogeneous element_, so it still meets that [comment's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40665647/what-is-the-data-model-required-for-such-data/40666410?noredirect=1#comment68587470_40666410) definition.

Comment: Wiki gives the definition

Comment: @overexchange [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List) gives "A list is any enumeration of a set of items."  Have not found a definition that matches the specificity of the [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40665647/what-is-the-data-model-required-for-such-data/40666410?noredirect=1#comment68587470_40666410).  Perhaps you can provide a link or detailed reference?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128484/discussion-between-overexchange-and-chux).

Comment: [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/626871/3317808) says, list is homogenous sequence

Answer (score 1):

The data structure you want appears to be a tree shape. Where each leaf is either an int, or it is a list of variable size. There is no current implementation of this I know of, so you would have to implement your own tree structure. You could implement this using a dynamic array like

```
struct Tree{
    struct Tree* list;
    //if leafOrBranch is true, consider this a branch and branchsize is the size of list, if it is false, consider this a leaf and branchsize is the content
    int branchSize;
    bool leafOrBranch;
}
```

This has the downside of needing the reallocate the memory in list when increasing the size of it, so an implementation could be done using a linked list or binary treee or something to speed it up.

Comment: Looks like an expression tree, which is n-ary

Answer (score 0):

To have such a structure in C you have much work to do (or link code of others). And SO is no code-writing service. However, I'll give you some pointers how to do that:

1. C does not support dynamic length arrays (lists) out of the box. (So-called variable length arrays are no help in your situation.) But you will find implementations for that in the web. (Usually list are linked lists of fixed-size buffers.)
2. C neither supports dynamic typing nor generic typing. To write generic code as such an array implementation has to have, usually the array does not store the payload itself, but a pointer to it. The pointer can be typed `void*`, what basically means "pointer to something". Therefore you can store a pointer to an integer number or to another list into it.
3. Or. You want to store integer numbers *and* lists of integer numbers side-by-side in the same list. This is unusual for C. Esp. C programs does not have meta information about its objects. There is no way to ask a `void *`, what type it is pointing to. Therefore you need a structure that stores, whether it holds a number or a list and then a component to hold a number (unused if it is a list) and a pointer to a list (unused if it is a number.) (You can optimize this a bit with castings or unions, but this is the first approach.)

So, putting all things together:

You need code, that manages a list. You will find that in the web.

You define your own structure holding a number or a pointer to another list and the type of data it stores.

Allocation of every list has to be done by yourself.

A long way to go. We will see you soon with additional Qs. ;-)

Comment: Question is just to show the type. declaration but not code writing

Comment: There is *no* type out of the box. C does not have it. It has no dynamic size type and it has no generic type.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you prefer a linked structure:

```
// A cell is a basic variant type whose value can be either
//  * An integer, or
//  * A pair of cells
struct cell_t;
struct pair_t;

// Enum of cell type, currently INT or PAIR
typedef enum { INT, PAIR } cell_type;

// Definition of type cell and pair, which are pointers to the respective structs
typedef struct cell_t* cell;
typedef struct pair_t* pair;

// Definition of pair_t: two pointers to cell (first and second)
// For a list structure, the type of second should always be PAIR.
struct pair_t {
    cell first;
    cell second;
};

// Definition of cell_t: type + union value
struct cell_t {
    cell_type type;
    union {
        int  i;
        pair p;
    } value;
};

// Constructors
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Returns an integer cell
cell Int(int i);
// Returns a pair cell
cell Pair(cell a, cell b);
// Returns a empty pair, type: PAIR, value.p==NULL
cell Nil();
```

To understand how this can represent the "deep" lists, have a read of this Wikipedia entry [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_(programming_language)#Lists).

Now we can create the example lists:

```
// Empty list
cell empty = Nil();

// [2, 3]
cell sublist23 = Pair(Int(2),
                    Pair(Int(3), empty));

cell sublist11 = Pair(Int(1), Pair(Int(1), empty));
cell sublist1_11 = Pair(Int(1), sublist11);

// [1, [2, 3], 4]
cell list1 = Pair(Int(1), 
                  Pair(sublist23, 
                       Pair(Int(4), empty)));
cell list2 = Pair(sublist1_11, sublist1_11);
```