# How to pull a list out of an array in Python

Tags: python

I need to pull an entire list out of an array. Essentially what I need my code to print the following.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [(1, 2, 3)]

if a != b
   print "a does not equal b"
else:
   print "a and b are the same!"

>>> a and b are the same!
```

Comment: Have you tried to do anything so far?

Comment: How deeply nested can `a` and `b` be?

Comment: which is a array and what do you mean pull?

Comment: Are you trying to test if both list are the same element-wise?

Comment: tried converting a into a tuple and comparing the two. tried to turn b into an array and compare the two. tried turning b into a tuple and comparing the two. I think i need to write a for loop that says if element 1 of a and b are the same and if element 2 of a and b are the same and if element 3 of a and b are the same then print that message but idk how to do that yet

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The [user *leaf* gave me the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41083419/how-to-pull-list-out-of-an-array-in-python#comment69372837_41083452).

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [(1, 2, 3)]

if tuple(b[0]) != a:
   print "a does not equal b"
else:
   print "a and b are the same!"
```

Result >>> a and b are the same!

Answer (score 1):

Just access the inner tuple and convert to list

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[(1,2,3)]

bl = list(b[0])

print(a == bl) # True
```

Comment: This is a decent answer for *one* interpretation of a poorly written question. I don't see much point in responding to questions which are so unclear

Comment: i'm still new to python. still unclear about the differences between lists, arrays, and tuples. if a tuple is defined as lists inside of lists with the syntax ((),(),...) and an array is defined to have the syntax [], then i thought b was a list inside of an array.

Comment: @DevinLiner No. `b` is a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) inside of a [list](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

Comment: @DevinLiner here is a pretty good discussion on the differences between lists and tuples http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626759/whats-the-difference-between-list-and-tuples

Comment: leaf gave me the answer

Comment: see the answer i provided.

Answer (score 0):

Converting it:

```
def con(st):
    res = []
    for x in st:
        res.append(x)
    return res
```

So the full code would be:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [(1, 2, 3)]
def con(st):
    res = []
    for x in st:
        res.append(x)
    return res
c = con(b[0])
if a != c:
   print "a does not equal b"
else:
   print "a and b are the same!"
```

Comment: Also you can use `list` instead of your `con` function.