# Too many to unpack tuple NLTK Chat

Tags: python, regex, tuples, nltk, chatbot

I have been working on a chat bot. I have used `nltk.chat` quite extensively for my bot. But I want to add more features to the pairs other than the default one. when i try to add new pair i'm, getting a error.

```
alex=Chat(pair,reflections)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/chat/util.py", in __init__
self._pairs = [(re.compile(x, re.IGNORECASE),y) for (x,y) in pairs]
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

my code:

```
pair=(
      (r'test (.*)',('a','b'))
     )
```

Comment: Please, use the formatting tools built right into the editor! Don't just add backticks thinking it'll format!

Comment: sure thing will do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pair is losing the structure you intended, for example:

```
pair=((((r'test (.*)', ('a','b')))))
```

would be the same as this:

```
('test (.*)', ('a', 'b'))
```

Where the first element is `'test (.*)'` and the second is `('a', 'b')`.

Basically just adding parentheses to a tuple structure does not mean you are nesting it. In order to achieve what you intended, you should be explicit in your definition of the tuple. If you change the `pair` initialization to this:

```
pair=( 
      (r'test (.*)', ('a','b')),
     )
```

(Note the **comma** before the final closing parenthesis)

Now your iteration would work. As the first element is `('test (.*)', ('a', 'b'))` and not just the string `test (.*)`

Hope this explains the cause of the error.

Comment: i never thought comma would be a problem

Comment: it is not working when i append it to an existing tuple

Comment: @AbuTahir can you please update your question with your current tuple? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is spot-on about the source of the problem, but it leaves out an important detail: Python style dictates that you [**use tuples only for collections in which each element has a specific role.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626759/whats-the-difference-between-lists-and-tuples) For undifferentiated collections, use `list` (square brackets). Each of the tuples you pass in the list `pair` is a pair of `(<regexp>, <data>)`, and hence properly written as a `tuple`. But `pair` itself is just a collection of such tuples, and should be written as a list, not as a tuple. As a bonus, list brackets are unambiguous and you don't need to remember to add a comma when your list only has one element:

```
# (works properly)
pair = [
      (r'test (.*)', ('a','b'))
     ]
```

Comment: the problem is to append my data to existing data structure so i have do it that way!

Comment: No you don't. You can't even append _anything_ to a tuple, don't you know that?

Comment: i have merged it .. like i created a new data structure for it. because the package i'm using it is like it need in such a fashion

Comment: "The package you are using" will not work if you change the round brackets to square brackets, thus passing a list? That's frankly unbelievable. Why don't you try it instead of telling me "it won't work".