# Numpy arrays with arraysd

Tags: python, numpy

Is it possible to fulfill numpy arrays with arrays?
I want to obtain a following structure without specifying values by hand

```
ves = np.zeros((12,12), dtype=object)
ves[0][0] = np.array([0,0,0])
ves[0][1] = np.array([0,0,0])
ves[0][2] = np.array([0,0,0])
ves[0][3] = np.array([0,0,0])
and so on...
```

In order to obtain the expected result, I have tried `ves = np.zeros((12,12), dtype=array)`, but it does not work.

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: It works fine, but I do not want to put values np.array([0,0,0]) by hand. I have tried specified dtype=array, but it didn't work

Comment: It seems like you want a 3D tensor. Can you try ves = np.zeros((12, 12, 3), dtype="int32")?

Comment: Do you understand the difference between this (12,12) object array and a (12,12,3) integer array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np 

v = np.zeros([12,12,3])
```

As per my understanding through your explanation, it seems you wanted a three dimension matrix where each cell needs three 0 values for 12*12 places. So the above code creates the value filled ndarray.

Comment: Thank you! Could you help me to understand what is the difference between np.zeros([12,12,3]) and np.zeros((12,12,3))?

Comment: There is no difference in the result. In the first case you input a list (marked by square brackets) in the second you input a tuple (round brackets).
See here for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626759/whats-the-difference-between-lists-and-tuples