# Difference between square bracket and parenthesis when array is being created in Python's NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

There are two options which create arrays:

```
x = numpy.array([[5, 5, 3, 2], [2, 1, 0, 9], [3, 7, 6, 0]])
y = numpy.array([(5, 5, 3, 2), (2, 1, 0, 9), (3, 7, 6, 0)])
```

But they have both same outputs.

```
[[5 5 3 2]
[2 1 0 9]
[3 7 6 0]]
```

They have both same type:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Which one is better and what is the difference?

Comment: For a numeric array like that they are interchangeable.  One's a list of lists the other a list of tuples.  When creating a structured array, the list of tuples is required, but that may be a more advanced topic

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Python** has [**tuples**](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) (with round brackets, like `(1,4,2,5)`) and **lists** (with square brackets, like `[1,4,2,5]`). Tuples are *immutable* ordered collections: once constructed, neither the length nor the elements can change (one can however alter the *state* of the individual elements given these are mutable). Both are used [for different purposes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626759/whats-the-difference-between-lists-and-tuples).

But if you construct a **2d numpy array**, then both will result in **the same array**, since numpy will simply read the elements *in* the list/tuple and copy the data into an array. It is only if for instance the rows have a different length, that numpy will construct an object array, and then it will reference to the tuples/lists.

Answer (score 2):

From numpy's point of view - there is no difference between the two options: the resulting arrays are "identical" in everything.