# extending the list by inserting list into list

Tags: python

I want to extend the list

```
s = 0,1

def hi(x):
    global s
    for i in range(x):
        s = 0,s
    return s

print hi(5)
```

the result of this will be '(0, (0, (0, (0, (0, (0, 1))))))'

But what I really want is (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1).
Do you have any idea doing it?

Comment: try: `s= (0,)+s` but that's not a list, but a `tuple`, and it's really inefficient to "insert" in a tuple.

Comment: you're mentionning lists, but those are not lists, those are `tuple`s (immutable, vs mutable))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do: `s= (0,)+s` to create a new `tuple` with leading `0` (instead of nesting the tuple at each iteration like you're doing.

But maybe the best way would be to prepend with a tuple of zeroes using multiplication (to avoid the loop):

```
s = (0,)*x + s
```

what bothers me even more is the need to use a `global`. I would pass `s` as a parameter:

```
def hi(x,s):
    return (0,)*x + s

print(hi(5,(0,1)))
```

resulting in the following `tuple`:

```
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
```

you may want to read about `list`s and `tuple`s and their differences: [What's the difference between lists and tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626759/whats-the-difference-between-lists-and-tuples). It's much easier to work with lists because of the available in-place operations they offer (*but* they cannot be used as dictionary keys or to be stored in `set`s)

Answer (score 1):

`s = 0, 1` is not a `list` but a `tuple` which is immutable.

It would be better to use proper list `s = [0, 1]` and then use [`insert()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) method.

```python
def hi(x, s):
    for _ in range(x):
        s.insert(0, 0)
    return s
```

Or event better to avoid the for loop:

```python
def hi(x, s):
    return ([0] * x) + s
```

If you want to use a [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences), then the answer from @Jean-François Fabre is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Given your particular use case Jean's answer would be better. But if you want to make that nested tuple into a single dimensional tuple, the more canonical operation is called `flatten()`. `flatten()` takes an arbitrarily-nested sequence and 'flattens' it into sequence with no nesting. `flatten()` isn't included in the python standard libraries, but is an incredibly useful operation included in many other languages. I took this below implementation from [here](https://rightfootin.blogspot.com/2006/09/more-on-python-flatten.html), which includes other implementations and discusses their strengths and weaknesses.

```
def flatten(l, ltypes=(list, tuple)):
    ltype = type(l)
    l = list(l)
    i = 0
    while i < len(l):
        while isinstance(l[i], ltypes):
            if not l[i]:
                l.pop(i)
                i -= 1
                break
            else:
                l[i:i + 1] = l[i]
        i += 1
    return ltype(l)
```

The usage is simple:

```
a = ((1, 2), (3,), (4, (5, 6)))
flatten(a)  # -> (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

a = hi(6)   # -> (0, (0, (0, (0, (0, (0, 1))))))
flatten(a)  # -> (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
```