# Format Python List using re

Tags: python, list

How can I format this string in a list 
from :

```
('1496\n8584\n172\n5988\n7184\n704\n3448\n6580\n8504\n', '')
```

to :

```
('1496','8584','172','5988','7184','704','3448','6580','8504')
```

I think the way is to use re.sub() but I'm having trouble with the '\n' not escaping

Comment: You mean this string-'1496\n8584\n172\n5988\n7184\n704\n3448\n6580\n8504\n'

Comment: So yes... by the way. You say you need a list `[...]`, but you are using a tuple `(...)`, can you clarify?

Comment: @Olivier: I suppose that tommy45 doesn't know difference between tuple and list in python.

Comment: @TigerTV.ru makes sense, they will learn right now

Answer (score 3):

You do not need `re.sub`, `str.split` will suffice.

```
t = ('1496\n8584\n172\n5988\n7184\n704\n3448\n6580\n8504\n', '')

out = t[0].split()

# out : ['1496', '8584', '172', '5988', '7184', '704', '3448', '6580', '8504']
```

If you want it exactly in the format you provided, you can cast back to a `tuple`. Note that when you use `(...)` you are creating a `tuple` and not a `list` as you mentionned.

```
out = tuple(t[0].split())

# out : ('1496', '8584', '172', '5988', '7184', '704', '3448', '6580', '8504')
```

Comment: why is `t` a tuple? it adds unnecessary complexity, just start with a string as in the question.

Comment: @avigil Because the question has been edited, I just did a rollback to preserve the initial intent which is to have a string inside a list/tuple.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this works-

```
a='1496\n8584\n172\n5988\n7184\n704\n3448\n6580\n8504\n'
b=a.split()
print(b)
```

Output-

```
['1496', '8584', '172', '5988', '7184', '704', '3448', '6580', '8504']
```

The `a.split()` splits the string by every occurrence of `\n`.

Comment: Or just use `.split()` to use consecutive whitespace characters as a single delimiter and then you won't end up with a trailing empty item. Should work fine for the OPs example.

Comment: Well said. Thanks. I edited to include your comment.

Comment: @Olivier Let the user clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `re.sub`, use `re.findall` to grab every run of digits:

```
import re
s = ('1496\n8584\n172\n5988\n7184\n704\n3448\n6580\n8504\n', '')
new_s = tuple(i for b in map(lambda x:re.findall('\d+', x), filter(None, s)) for i in b)
```

Output:

```
('1496', '8584', '172', '5988', '7184', '704', '3448', '6580', '8504')
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. Use [split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) function for strings.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
s = ('1496\n8584\n172\n5988\n7184\n704\n3448\n6580\n8504\n', '')
output=s[0].split()
print(output)
```

output you expected as list:

```
['1496', '8584', '172', '5988', '7184', '704', '3448', '6580', '8504']
```

If you want to get a tuple, use [tuple](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tuple_tuple.htm) function to convert.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
s = ('1496\n8584\n172\n5988\n7184\n704\n3448\n6580\n8504\n', '')
output=tuple(s[0].split())
print(output)
```

output as a tuple:

```
('1496', '8584', '172', '5988', '7184', '704', '3448', '6580', '8504')
```

Differences between tuple and list in python you can get [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/626871/9210255).

Answer (score 0):

This code resolved my problem

```
output = ('1496\n8584\n172\n5988\n7184\n704\n3448\n6580\n8504\n', '')
output = str(output)
output = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9 .]|n','',output)
output = output.split()
print output
```