# python3: brackets are also output when printing

Tags: python, python-3.x

Halli, I'm a beginner in Python. I learn with books. When describing a tuple, the brackets are also output when printing. This is not the case in the book. Do I have a mistake somewhere?

```
test=(12,12)
print (test) 

Python 3.5.4 (default, Feb 11 2018, 12:46:54) 
[GCC 6.4.0] on linux
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
=================== RESTART: /home/fridolin/python/test.py ===================
(12, 12)
>>>
```

http://edv-bildung.de/question-in-python

Comment: is that link a reference to the book?

Comment: The code you posted in your question and the code in the screenshot are literally the same. Where's that difference in output you're talking about?

Comment: can you copy the original code in the book so we can see what the "case is in the book"

Comment: `test` is a tuple. Because this is an important aspect of `test` the parentheses are also printed to make this clear.  That is, you seem to think that just the numbers should be printed, but `test` isn't just two numbers, it's a tuple of two numbers, that is, a specific type of python object.

Comment: the code is from the book. I would not need to take a screenshot. The book displays as output 12, 12. I get as output (12, 12) - why?

Comment: Many thanks. i learn :-)

Comment: the text is wrong probably , () defines the characteristic of a tuple like test=[12,12] gives square brackets in printing

Comment: The book may be using python 2.

Answer (score 1):

No this is not a mistake. When a tuple is printed it will be displayed as ().

Take a look at this.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/626871/9439504

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Perhaps you can add more details, to explain better the most important parts of your answer. Have a read of [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more information. Also, once you get more reputation, you will be able to post this as a comment rather than an answer, which would be more appropriate.