# How to mathematically change value pairs in a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm storing 2D coordinate pairs as the value in a dictionary.  It seems to be treating them as integers (when I print them there are no quotation marks).  Adding 10 to the value  simply appends 10, however... so it's a tuple?

```
import random
d={}
num_points=8
def find_rand_points(num_points):
    for i in range(num_points):
        d[i]=(random.randrange(-250,251),random.randrange(-250,251))

d[0][0]=d[0][0]+[10]
```

I'm confused why they're tuples in the first place, because I thought randrange would return integers.  I can see why it's not working though, since tuples are immutable.  I'm trying to get them to add like an array, but am pretty new to Python.

Comment: `,` makes a tuple.  You have one between two calls to `randrange`

Comment: Why not use a numpy matrix?

Comment: @StephenRauch: Well, in this case, they did provide explicit delimiters, so it's more the fault of the outer parens being used where square brackets were needed. If they'd used `[random.randrange(-250,251),random.randrange(-250,251)]` it would work, no change to the comma.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, I was responding to *I'm confused why they're tuples*

Comment: Gotcha, how should I be doing this then, if not using a comma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tuples are immutable objects in Python. This means that they cannot be changed once they are initialized. First how can you access this tuple?

Let's make your dictionary as follows

```
import random
d={}
num_points=8
for i in range(num_points):
    d[i]=(random.randrange(-250,251),random.randrange(-250,251))
print(d)
```

> {0: (229, -137),  1: (178, 71),  2: (7, 19),  3: (180, 150),  4:
>   (-126, -65),  5: (-235, 80),  6: (-174, -241),  7: (200, 16)}

Then to access one of these 2D points we can do

```
d[0]
```

> (229, -137)

Then we can try and access the first number of this coordinate as

```
d[0][0]
```

> 229

But now lets try to change this value as

```
d[0][0] = d[0][0] + 10
```

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 d[0][0] = d[0][0] + 10
>
> TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

This does not work. It tells us that a tuple does not support item assignment. It cannot be changed.

---

## Use a list

You should instead use a list. Replace your `(  )` to `[  ]` in the coordinate creation step.

```
import random
d={}
num_points=8
for i in range(num_points):
    d[i]=[random.randrange(-250,251),random.randrange(-250,251)]
```

Now we can do this and it will add 10 to the first dimension of the first coordinate.

```
d[0][0] = d[0][0] + 10
```

---

## Use a numpy matrix

You can set each row to be each coordinate and then the columns represent the first and second value in the coordinate.

```
import numpy as np

num_points=8
d = np.zeros((num_points, 2))
for i in range(num_points):
    d[i,0], d[i,1]= random.randrange(-250,251), random.randrange(-250,251)

d[0]
```

> array([-233.,   92.])

```
d[0,1] += 100
```

> array([-233.,  192.])

Comment: Alternatively, you could keep using `tuple`s and do `d[0] = d[0][0] + 10, d[0][1]` (constructing a new `tuple` with the incremented value as a component, and replacing). Or slightly more efficiently (avoids excessive repeated lookups of `d[0]` and indexing of same), `a, b = d[0]`, `d[0] = a + 10, b`

Comment: @ShadowRanger Would there be a benefit to keeping this as a tuple?  I'm trying to come up with a scenario where that would be useful.

Comment: @fakedane, no problem. I would actually recommend using a numpy matrix to do this. Have an 'n*2' matrix where you can store the x-values in the first column, and the y-values in the second column. Each row represents a different point.

Comment: @fakedane: The same reasons [you use `tuple`s in general](https://stackoverflow.com/q/626759/364696); preventing in-place modification, reducing memory usage (on 64 bit modern Python, a two-`tuple` adds 64 bytes of overhead, vs. 80 for a len 2 `list`, and the real cost is higher given allocator overhead; the `list` is two allocations, the `tuple` is one), as a mnemonic for a lightweight heterogeneous object rather than a homogeneous sequence, etc. If those benefits don't apply, or mutations are frequent, sure, go w/`list`, but if mutations are rare, the cost of `tuple` replacement is trivial.