# Creating a new tuple vs indexing and assigning to an array

Tags: python, performance, data-structures, time-complexity

Given the two data structures, Array and tuple, which is more complex, creating a new tuple or indexing and assigning a number to a particular index in an array.

For example, given the tuple/array containing `x, y`.

```
(0,0),[0,0]
```

If you want to change the two `x, y` values, is it quicker to create a new tuple or to index and assign to the array?

```
(0,1), [0, 1]
```

does the most efficient data structure change with the length?

Comment: Creating a new tuple is a more expensive operation than updating an element in a list. See here for details: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: That is a *list* not an array. Creating a new tuple is linear on the size of a tuple (time and space). Mutating an element of a *list* is a constant time operation. But if you are always going to mutate every element in a list, that is also linear time (although constant space).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626759/whats-the-difference-between-lists-and-tuples?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa