# Is there a better (more efficient) way to remove an item from a tuple?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of tuples, from which I am removing the ith element. Right now I'm doing this with:

```
map(lambda e: list(e)[:i] + list(e)[(i + 1):], data)
```

which converts the tuple to a list (twice!) and then slices out the element. The result means that I have lists instead of tuples- but this is perfectly fine. Is there a faster way of doing this, possibly by converting each tuple to a list in a separate map operation?

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to convert to a list at all. Just slice the tuple; slicing doesn't mutate a tuple, it creates a new object:

```
map(lambda e: e[:i] + e[i:], data)
```

Not that the above slice operations are any use, because slicing to `i` and from `i` would create *the exact same tuple*. You want to add 1 to the start of the second slice if `i` should be omitted:

```
map(lambda e: e[:i] + e[i + 1:], data)
```

Demo:

```
>>> t = (41, 42, 45, 54, 81, 162)
>>> t[:3] + t[3:]  # same tuple again
(41, 42, 45, 54, 81, 162)
>>> t[:3] + t[4:]  # skip index 3
(41, 42, 45, 81, 162)
```

You may want to reconsider using tuples here; tuples are really more designed for *heterogenous data structures*; tuples have structure, lists have order. See [What's the difference between lists and tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626759/whats-the-difference-between-lists-and-tuples)

Comment: Thanks, the only reason I am dealing with a tuple is that it is what the numpy function is giving me.

Answer (score 3):

No need to wrap this to a list, you can just:

```
map(lambda e: (*e[:i], *e[i+1:]), data)
```

But these approaches all will take *O(m n)* time with *m* the arity of the tuples and *n* the number of tuples.

The above will also process *siceable* iterables, so not per se tuples. Furthermore the result is always a tuple. For example for a `range(..)` object:

```
>>> i=3
>>> list(map(lambda e: (*e[:i], *e[i+1:]), [range(1,7)]))
[(1, 2, 3, 5, 6)]
```

This is not per se wanted behavior. One can also use `e[:i] + e[i+1:]`, this will then raise an error for a `range(..)` object. For a `list`, it will return a `list`. There is not an "inherent" better approach: it depends on the use case.

Comment: This is not actually different from concatenation though.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: these are not *functionally* equivalent. I prefer using iterable unpacking, since this will work with any slicable iterable, whereas for a list of lists, this will result in a list, for `range(..)` objects, this will construct a tuple as well, but indeed for tuples itself, there is no difference. So it gives more guarantees at the "output side", and takes more types at the "input side".

Comment: Fair enough, iterable unpacking does operate differently when `e` is *not* a tuple. It depends on the use-case if you actually want to support arbitrary iterators or if that should be an error.