# How do I insert a tuple in a structure at a specific place?

Tags: python, tuples

I currently have the following structure:

```
[('file_name', '', '', {'Key': [(msg_1), (msg_2)]})]
```

I want to insert the following tuple:

```
(time.struct_time(tm_year=2019, tm_mon=5, tm_mday=22, tm_hour=20, tm_min=19, tm_sec=54, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=142, tm_isdst=1))
```

Such that I end up with:

```
[('file_name', (time.struct_time(tm_year=2019, tm_mon=5, tm_mday=22, tm_hour=20, tm_min=19, tm_sec=54, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=142, tm_isdst=1),'', '', {'Key': [(msg_1), (msg_2)]}))]
```

Note that the closing bracket placement of the tuple of `time.struct_time` is required to be before the list ends (to enclose the remainder of the contents of `msg1` and `msg2`).

I tried variations of using `zip` and converting to a `list` using `insert` with no luck.

Comment: You cannot `insert` into an existing tuple, you will need to create a new tuple in place of it ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tuples are immutable objects in python. It's not possible to change an existing tuple. Please take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626759/whats-the-difference-between-lists-and-tuples/626871#626871).

However, you can create another tuple:

```
a = [('file_name', '', '', {'Key': [(msg_1), (msg_2)]})]
b = (time.struct_time(tm_year=2019, tm_mon=5, tm_mday=22, tm_hour=20, tm_min=19, tm_sec=54, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=142, tm_isdst=1))
c = [a[0][0], b, *a[0][1:]]
```

Note that `*` before `a[0][1:]` unpack the selected slice of the tuple.