# Why do tuples not get changed whereas lists do?

Tags: python

Why does only the first tuple change in example ***II*** whereas both lists get changed in example ***I***? Please consider these two programs and their respective output (***I*** and ***II***).

***I.***

```
L1 = [1,2,3,4]
L2 = L1
L2.append(5)
print("L1: ", L1)
print("L2: ", L2)
```

**Output:**

```
L1: [1,2,3,4,5]
L2: [1,2,3,4,5]
```

---

***II.***

```
L1=(1,2,3,4)
L2=L1
L2 += (5,)
print("L1: ", L1)
print("L2: ", L2)
```

**Output:**

```
L1: (1,2,3,4)
L2: (1,2,3,4,5)
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626759/whats-the-difference-between-lists-and-tuples?rq=1

Comment: Also linked to [Why are list changes reflected in all copies?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/240178/9917694). The main idea is that lists are mutable and `L1 = L2` means both variables refer to the same object. Tuples are immutable so doing `+=` will create a new object. Although it appears to work in-place, it’s just assigning the result back to `L2`

Comment: To illustrate what @NChauhan correctly said, try: `L2=L1; print(id(L1)); print(id(L2)); L2 += (5,); print(id(L2))`. That will show that L1 and L2 originally have the same ID - that is, they refer to the same object. After the `+=` step, L2 will have a new ID because it now points to a brand new object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between lists and tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626759/whats-the-difference-between-lists-and-tuples)

Comment: TL;DR: tuples are immutable, if you assign one to the other, you're getting a fresh copy - lists are mutable, if you assign one to the other, they're both the same list.

Answer (score 0):

In `List` when you use this '=' assignment operator, it does not creates new reference, it refers same object.

In `Tuple` when you use this '=' assignment operator, it creates new reference.

Refer below code, check the output of ID.

```
L1 = [1,2,3,4]
L2 = L1
L2.append(5)
print("L1: ", L1)
print("L2: ", L2)
print("ID of L1: ", id(L1))
print("ID of L2: ", id(L2))
# Output =
# L1:  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
# L2:  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
# ID of L1:  2598160167616
# ID of L2:  2598160167616
# -------------------------------------------
L1=(1,2,3,4)
L2=L1
L2 += (5,)
print("L1: ", L1)
print("L2: ", L2)
print("ID of L1: ", id(L1))
print("ID of L2: ", id(L2))
# Output =
# L1:  (1, 2, 3, 4)
# L2:  (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
# ID of L1:  2598161745696
# ID of L2:  2598161718864
# -------------------------------------------
```

Comment: `In Tuple when you use this '=' assignment operator, it creates new object.` Wrong. *Everything* in python would create a new reference when written such as `b = a` (and thus, a new object is not created). It's only that tuples are immutable, so `L2 += (5,)` is where `L2` starts to point to a newly created tuple.

Answer (score 0):

In example 1, we have a list. **List is mutable**, which means once the lists are created they can be changed later. Hence the **memory location at which they are stored remains the same**.
"L2=L1" statement is just providing reference of L1 to L2 and when changes are done in L2 they are reflected in L1 as well.

In example 2, we have tuples. **Tuples on the other hand are immutable**, which means they cannot be changed further. And that is the reason why L1 was not changing along with L2 because both of them are **separate objects with separate memory references**.

Answer (score -1):

Tuples are immutable, so only L2 is changing. As lists are mutable, both are changing then.