# Typing: Annotate a list within a list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, typing

I have the following type and cant figure how to annotate it:
`[[str, int]]`

I cant use  `List[List[str,int]]` due

> TypeError: Parameters to generic types must be types. Got slice(<class 'str'>, typing.Any, None).

Can i use Tuple despite having a list `[str, int]`: `List[Tuple[str,int]]`?

And `List[List[Union[str, int]]` does not reveal order: `str` before `int`. I try to annotate the https://redis.io/commands/xread response for redis-py

Comment: I don't think this is supported; it's a mild misuse of `list` (which is logically intended to be a homogeneous sequence); `typing.Tuple` defaults to heterogeneous with fixed length with `Ellipsis` allowing it to be homogeneous with variable length (when used as immutable `list`), but `typing.List` (and `typing.Sequence`, the more generic version) don't have a reversed behavior to switch to fixed length heterogeneous behavior.

Comment: appreciate your words, yet spagetti for my brain

Comment: I'd read [this answer to "What's the difference between lists and tuples?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/626871/364696); it's a longer way of describing the difference in *intent*, beyond the much more minor differences in *function* (which is just mutable vs. immutable). You *can* use `tuple`s as just immutable `list`s (and `typing` supports it, because immutable `list`s are useful), but `typing` doesn't support `list`s used as mutable `tuple`s because the use cases are much more limited (and usually better achieved with class instances, especially now that the `dataclasses` module exists).

Comment: No, the `list` type does not support this.