# why tuple is necessary in Python?

Tags: python, list, tuples

It seems to me that the only difference between a tuple and a list is that a tuple is unchangable.
If this is true, defining a new type of lists by requiring them to be unchangable seems to be more intuitive than bothering to introduce a new name (tuple) and new syntax (round-brackets).
Is tuple important enough for a new name and syntax?

Comment: The main difference is what you are signaling to the reader of your code that this data structure should do. A list is changble, dynamic in size, and should contain homogenous data. A tuple is general short, contains heterogenous data (in the same order, i.e. (str, int, bool)* and represent as sort of *record*. They are more compact than lists, and the order matters.

Comment: Note, the syntax isn't round-brackets. *commas* make the tuple. e.g. `a_tuple = 'foo', 42`

Comment: I do not think this question is opinion-based. I am just asking the reason behind a data structure design.

Comment: See this duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626759/whats-the-difference-between-lists-and-tuples

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillage Except of the empty one, which works without.

Answer (score 1):

- Iterating through a tuple is faster than compared to a list (by a small amount)
- Tuples that contain immutable elements can be used as a key for a dictionary, list is not hashable

There can be many more reasons like passing data that you don't want any code to change but these are the major ones

Comment: "iterating through a tuple is faster than compared to a list" barely. That's never a real consideration. I wouldn't consider it a major consideration at all.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have added that in the answer now, thanks for pointing out