# Check if item is in an array / list

Tags: python, arrays, contains

If I've got an array of strings, can I check to see if a string is in the array without doing a `for` loop?  Specifically, I'm looking for a way to do it within an `if` statement, so something like this:

```
if [check that item is in array]:
```

Comment: I think the question is already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542738/python-find-in-list)

Comment: Or better here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12934190/is-there-a-short-contains-function-for-lists

Answer (score 597, accepted):

Assuming you mean "list" where you say "array", you can do

```
if item in my_list:
    # whatever
```

This works for any collection, not just for lists. For dictionaries, it checks whether the given key is present in the dictionary.

Comment: @jdi, and that loop will run much faster than the one coded explicitly in Python, not to mention being easier to read.

Comment: `in` is real nice, but I have to stress how nice using a `lambda` is for cases where we want to check if a substring is in a list of strings.

Comment: @T.Woody [I'd use a generator expression or a list comprehension for that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4843172/279627), not a lambda.

Comment: And if you need to flip the condition it is `if item not in my_list:`

Answer (score 22):

I'm also going to assume that you mean "list" when you say "array." Sven Marnach's solution is good. If you are going to be doing repeated checks on the list, then it might be worth converting it to a set or frozenset, which can be faster for each check. Assuming your list of strs is called `subjects`:

```
subject_set = frozenset(subjects)
if query in subject_set:
    # whatever
```

Answer (score 8):

Use a lambda function.

Let's say you have an array:

```
nums = [0,1,5]
```

Check whether 5 is in `nums` in **Python 3.X**:

```
(len(list(filter (lambda x : x == 5, nums))) > 0)
```

Check whether 5 is in `nums` in **Python 2.7**:

```
(len(filter (lambda x : x == 5, nums)) > 0)
```

---

This solution is more robust. You can now check whether any number satisfying a certain *condition* is in your array `nums`.

For example, check whether any number that is greater than or equal to 5 exists in `nums`:

```
(len(filter (lambda x : x >= 5, nums)) > 0)
```

Comment: This works with Python2. With Python 3.7, you will get this error: `TypeError: object of type 'filter' has no len()`

Answer (score 3):

You have to use .values for arrays. 
for example say you have dataframe which has a column name ie, test['Name'], you can do

```
if name in test['Name'].values :
   print(name)
```

for a normal list you dont have to use .values

Comment: I think you need a Pandas DataFrame object to use .values.

Answer (score -5):

You can also use the same syntax for an array. For example, searching within a Pandas series:

```
ser = pd.Series(['some', 'strings', 'to', 'query'])

if item in ser.values:
    # do stuff
```