# Is there a short contains function for lists?

Tags: python, list, search, collections, contains

Given a list `xs` and a value `item`, how can I check whether `xs` contains `item` (i.e., if any of the elements of `xs` is equal to `item`)? Is there something like `xs.contains(item)`?

---

<sub>For performance considerations, see [Fastest way to check if a value exists in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571635).</sub>

Comment: Your question implies you're only interested in *list contains item*, not *list contains sublist? /tuple/ set/ frozenset/...?*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fastest way to check if a value exists in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571635/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-value-exists-in-a-list)

Answer (score 1034, accepted):

Use:

```
if my_item in some_list:
    ...
```

Also, inverse operation:

```
if my_item not in some_list:
    ...
```

It works fine for lists, tuples, sets and dicts (check keys).

**Note** that this is an O(n) operation in lists and tuples, but an O(1) operation in sets and dicts.

Comment: With a list containing numpy arrays, will this check for numpy instances or values inside the numpy instances?

Comment: Beware ! This matches while this is very probably what you did not expect: `o='--skip';  o in ("--skip-ias");   # returns True !`

Comment: @AlexF: That matches because `("--skip-ias")` is not a tuple, but a string (the parentheses do nothing, just like `(1)` is just an integer). If you want a 1-tuple, you need to add a comma after the single item: `("--skip-ias",)` (or `(1,)`).

Comment: Note that if you're comparing characters, this is case insensitive.

Comment: @Tillson don’t you mean that this is case sensitive? in my Python 3.11.5 repl `"a" in "A"` evaluates to `False`.

Answer (score 72):

In addition to what other have said, you may also be interested to know that what `in` does is to call the `list.__contains__` method, that you can define on any class you write and can get extremely handy to use python at his full extent.

A dumb use may be:

```
>>> class ContainsEverything:
    def __init__(self):
        return None
    def __contains__(self, *elem, **k):
        return True


>>> a = ContainsEverything()
>>> 3 in a
True
>>> a in a
True
>>> False in a
True
>>> False not in a
False
>>>
```

Answer (score 7):

I came up with this one liner recently for getting `True` if a list contains any number of occurrences of an item, or `False` if it contains no occurrences or nothing at all. Using `next(...)` gives this a default return value (`False`) and means it should run significantly faster than running the whole list comprehension.

`list_does_contain = next((True for item in list_to_test if item == test_item), False)`

Comment: In my case i have a list of object called Category and a need it to test only for the property Link, so this solutions fits better in my case. Thanks

Comment: `any(item == test_item for item in list_to_test)` would work too, I think?

Answer (score 5):

The list method `index` will return `-1` if the item is not present, and will return the index of the item in the list if it is present. Alternatively in an `if` statement you can do the following:

```
if myItem in list:
    #do things
```

You can also check if an element is not in a list with the following if statement:

```
if myItem not in list:
    #do things
```

Comment: The `index` method does not return -1 if the element is not present, it throws a `ValueError` exception.

Answer (score 2):

There is also the list method:

```
[2, 51, 6, 8, 3].__contains__(8)
# Out[33]: True
[2, 51, 6, 3].__contains__(8)
# Out[33]: False
```

Comment: This is covered by Ant's answer already.

Answer (score -1):

There is one another method that uses `index`. But I am not sure if this has any fault or not.

```
list = [5,4,3,1]
try:
    list.index(2)
    #code for when item is expected to be in the list
    print("present")
except:
    #code for when item is not expected to be in the list
    print("not present")
```

Output:

> not present

Comment: It runs in O(N) time and try-except is slower than if checks