# Python Coding - Vending machine - How to get the user to only enter certain coins?

Tags: python

I'm doing a controlled assessment on python. One of the tasks is to create a vending machine under certain criteria. I'm pretty bad a python and I'm probably being an idiot and doing this wrong.

I want the user to input only 10,20,50,1.00 coins. If the user enters anything other than these coins, I want it to print "Machine doesn't accept these coins".

This is what I have so far:

```
inp = input("Enter Coins, Note: Machine only accepts 10, 20, 50 and 100 coins: ")
value = [10,20,50,100]
if inp != value:
    print("Machine doesn't accept these coins")
else:
    print("What would you like to buy?")
```

Comment: `inp != value` compares the values of `inp` and `value`. You'll want to check if `value` [contains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12934190/is-there-a-short-contains-function-for-lists-in-python) `inp`.

Comment: `input` will return a string, not an integer, so be careful about how you compare types.

Comment: @dirn so how would I do that? Would it have to be input(int( ?

Comment: You can either use `inp = int(input(...))` (this could raise a `ValueError` if the user's input can't be converted to an integer, and it only works for one value) or you can use strings in `values = ['10', '20', ...]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, you want:

```
if any(int(coin) not in value for coin in inp.split()):
    print("Machine doesn't accept these coins")
```

What this basically does it [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) up the input into separate coins, converts them to integers, (because the items in `values` are integers) then checks if it is `not in values`, which of course would mean it is invalid.

Finally, this is done until it finds an invalid coin (take a look at [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#any)). At that, it will `print` that the coins are invalid. If it does not, then it will continue to `else`.

Comment: thanks bro, it worked:)) The only thing I don't understand is how coin is not an invalid syntax?

Comment: @SteveS while we are going over each value in `inp`, coin just represents the current value that we are analyzing, it doesn't exist as a variable globally, it is just a representation. That is why there is no error.

Comment: This is a very pretty bit of code using a *generator expression*. `for coin in inp.split()` says "take the list created by `inp.split()` and assign each value in that list in turn to `coin`. For each value of `coin`, we evaluate the expression `int(coin) not in value` (meaning "`true` if the value of coin is *not* in the array `value`, `false` if not); that resulting list of booleans gets passed to `any()`, whose value is `true` if any value in the list was `true`, `false` otherwise. A spiffy piece of code in a single expression.

Comment: @JoeMcMahon Very correct and thank you for giving a much better explanation than me. However it is not a list comprehension but a generator expression.

Comment: You can tell I'm not primarily a Python programmer! - thanks for the correction. Fixed.

Comment: @JoeMcMahon Thanks for the help both of you, appreciate it!!