# Python Hangman issue

Tags: python

I am trying to make a hangman game. So far, I have a list of words for the program to randomly choose from:

```
a = random.choice(hangman_words))
```

Then I have the program display the number of characters in the word using the `len` function. That all works like it should. The problem I'm having is after prompting the user for a letter, I need the program to tell the user if the letter is correct or not and I don't know how to do that.
Thanks

Comment: Can you show us some code please? Also, please read this to know how to get the most out of SO: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Think of your word as an array of letters. Look at this question to help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12934190/is-there-a-short-contains-function-for-lists-in-python

Comment: Perhaps a list of words is the wrong way to structure your data. If you use a string then you can simply do character in string like this `'h' in 'hello'`.

Comment: A quick google search gives you plenty of examples to work with, from simple (http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/code-snippets-source-code/game-hangman) to more complex (https://inventwithpython.com/chapter9.html https://gist.github.com/DevDarren/4199441 http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578551-the-game-of-hangman-in-python/ ). Try and read those with a language guide nearby, and try and make one for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

maybe try an if statement? so for example

```
if userAnswer == theRandomLetter then
  print "Correct!"
else:
  print "Try again!"
```

and after that you could use a loop to repeat the process if the answer is incorrect

Comment: I'll try it out. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code to test your condition.

```
answer = raw_input("enter a letter:")

incorrect_letters = ["a","y","Y","q","Q","p"] 


for x in incorrect_letters:
    if answer == x:
        print "incorrect choice"
```

Here is some code to generate characters:

```
char_list = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m",
            "n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z",
            "A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","k","L","M",
            "N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]

num_char= 100

my_char = [random.choice(char_list) for i in xrange(num_char)]
```